# how to send base64 formatted string to PHP server using POST method, ios

Tags: ios, http, post, base64, nsmutableurlrequest

Hello i am new to iOS and need to submit an image to php server. For this i 
have converted image into base64 format. and need to send this base64 string to 
PHP server.
Code i am using fot this is, Please help i am completely new in ios

```
// Create your request string with parameter name as defined in PHP file
NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"comment=%@",@"test data"];
  // Create Data from request
NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];
request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.sdevices.ru/flashrecorder/speechtotext.php"]];
// set Request Type
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
// Set content-type
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
// Set Request Body
[request setHTTPBody:myRequestData];
// Now send a request and get Response
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];
// Log Response
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",response); // here you get reasponse string

if ([response isEqualToString:@"Speech text!"]) {
    UIAlertView *alrt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Flash Recorder" message:@"Text is submitted!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alrt show];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i this post there is answer for base 64 encode a data

[Base64 Encoding for NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245300/base64-encoding-for-nsstring)

for NSData from string

```
NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and NSString from data

`NSString* str =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];`

this snippet directly from my code does post connection easily

```
-(BOOL) doPostConnection:(ServiceProps*) props delegate:(id<URLConnectionDelegate>) delegate
{
     NSString *post = props.contentString;
     NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
     NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:props.connectionURL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Data-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
     NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:delegate];
     return conn != nil;
}
```

props -> basic class for wrap content string and url

```
@interface ServiceProps : NSObject
@property () NSString* contentString;
@property () NSURL* connectionURL;
@end
```

delegate -> An interface class which contains your post service logic it 
inside depends on your service

```
@protocol URLConnectionDelegate <NSObject>

- (id) initWithConnectionDelegate:(id<ConnectionDelegate>)delegate;
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data;
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
@end
```

Comment: thiats ok i am asking about sending data to server

Comment: doPostConnection:(ServiceProps*) props delegate:(id<URLConnectionDelegate>) delegate plase exaplain this parameters