# Convert this url to base 64

Tags: iphone, base64

I tried this way but it's not working.

This is the url to convert to base 64

```
NSString *strUrlB64 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ShiftSharerfree_new&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5TGlmdFNoYXJlcmZyZWVfbmV3Il0"];

NSData *dataUrl = [NSData dataFromBase64String:strUrlB64];
```

Then tried to send this to another url.

```
NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://server39.pnht.com/360ad/apps/ads/%@/android/136/ord0.910950258132325?json=1&package_url=%@",self.mStrPid, dataUrl];
```

It is giving me output: NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://server39.pbgs.com/360ads/apps/ad/%@/android/1360/ord0.910950252132325?json=1&package_url=%@",self.mStrPid, url];

It is not base 64. please guide how to get base 64 out of it.

Comment: `dataFromBase64String` does the opposite of what you're trying to do.  See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838263/converting-nsstring-to-base64-data-for-xml-serialization

Comment: I am not getting bro i am trying from yesterday please provide the proper solution of it.

Comment: `base64EncodedString` method will convert string to base64 string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using base 64 to encode and decode **some text**, 
 can u tell me if it works with **URLs**,

```
- (NSString *)base64Encode:(NSString *)plainText
 {
    NSData *plainTextData = [plainText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *base64String = [plainTextData base64EncodedString];
    return base64String;
 }

- (NSString *)base64Decode:(NSString *)base64String
{
    NSData *plainTextData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:base64String];
    NSString *plainText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:plainTextData   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return plainText;
}
```

Comment: Ya thanks it is working but showing = instead of last character.

Comment: aHR0cHM6Ly9wbGF5Lmdvb2dsZS5jb20vc3RvcmUvYXBwcy9kZXRhaWxzP2lkPWNv
bS5TaGlmdFNoYXJlcmZyZWVfbmV3JmZlYXR1cmU9c2VhcmNoX3Jlc3VsdCM/dD1X
MjUxYkd3c01Td3lMREVzSW1OdmJTNVRhR2xtZEZOb1lYSmxjbVp5WldWZmJtVjNJ
bDA=