# Cast base64binary to image on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, base64, webservice-client

can anybody help me what to do to convert this (bellow) to image on iPhone, please?

```
<base64Binary>
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAdcAAAEjCAYAAABgh0vOAAAABGdBTUEAALGOfPtRkwAAACBjSFJNAAB6JQAAgIMAAPn/AACA6QAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF2+SX8VGAAAACXBIWXMAAAsSAAALEgHS3X78AAD/hklEQVR4Xuy9BZykZ5X9DyQjGWmXqmp3d3d372mZnu6RHnd3d/fIxN1diUOw4CyysNhvsV0gLCxOApHz/963Z/hnswECJCyBCp+Hqq6uLnmn6j3POffcc9/TlB0d+B7vf94j4D0C/5RHQNJ7vMt7DLyfgbf/M/Cexoyoi/4pzyreN+09At4j4AVW7+bC+xl4hz4D3tOL9wh4j8A/8RHwMpa3n7F4j6n3mNpnwPuf9wh4j8A/8RHwAoEXCLyfgXfmM/BPfFrxvnXvEfAeAe+J9Z05sXqPq/e4es8u3iPgPQL/xEfACwJeEPB+Bt6Zz8A/8WnF+9a9R8B7BLwn1nfmxOo9rt7j6j27eI+A9wj8Ex8BLwh4QcD7GXhnPgP/xKcV71v3HgHvEfCeWN+ZE6v3uHqPq/fs4j0C3iPwT3wEvCDgBQHvZ+Cd+Qz8E59WvG/dewS8R8B7Yn1nTqze4+o9rt6zi/cIeI/AP/ER8IKAFwS8n4F35jPwT3xa8b517xHwHgHvifWdObF6j6v3uHrPLt4j4D0C/8RHwAsCXhDwfgbemc/AP/FpxfvWvUfAewS8J9Z35sTqPa7e4+o9u3iPgPcI/HMfgffy9v+a9c999Lzv/p/uCLzVjdM/3YHxvmHvEfgnPQJvBUDfx7F5q+utPJ7dx/uf9wj8Qx0BL7j+Q/1zet+M9wj8RUfgDwHgmwGozXW+KCuv/GK7tNXQ0DFu+szNk1dsPDapa/qaSQOLNky6/OaHfKtal024cJ/zl2/2eH8MfP+iN/N3+kfeTcbf6T/MO/WyvOD6Th1Z7+N6j8Df/xF4sxP+6wHQAc/zy8B0nK0TN92f+7Ev/XzPDTd+ZftDD39mzV33Pn1wx8Ebr7vytmevWb3n2qu3XnbjdZ//+vfv33/5x0439B5ZM31wz8y+oc2lbZ3zY6qqOqYUFbVcEh2dbo914bHfCLrvVsB9qwD619zvD36q0gqG35tdNGLH1Pvf38ER8ILr38E/gvcleI/A3/gIvPHk/maA+nsw5bWNtzVn7kqfQydvrHni05998Ge/+LlueeBRrTl8TIs2rdOMhQs1OHeZKnpnaMb2dfrKd76pz335P3T8zNNaueYKzVm888ezF2x4fv7CDTcOzVhxbnBw5eHu7sVbOjrmLaivmllTXTYQUV3TNeVdCLh/Duu34/z7DcvECfHj/PxTJ/r6JU6a7J886aKJ+ZMvHpdnbP/PYfi//+iUNS67uKpp+aS65uVegP0bf6He7Om84Pp38I/gfQneI/A2H4G3wozeCqDaid7WxJvvvb/gwSefO7lu177/WrtnvxasXKO47Exd4nZrcrBH7vAE+QVFakpomMLzU9U0u09PPveUXvjJz7V49SlVNi9UdesCNXQuUEffPHX3LVTf9KUamrni1RkjK743MH3Rc9OHllzR0798TW3j6GBxWX9dXl5n2OvB6M8EnT90DN6uQ/2nWP//AFKe9OKJAR7Xe1wZHY2jR5b3TL91TXj4rO3x8W3H4+Nrznrias5ODem57L3j2o8gtM+5+JLGet+g2ug/8f7/x2tIzqx9X/fQzot6p2/31rDfrn/lv+JxvOD6Vxw87596j8Df4Ai8FaB8Kyf6Pyn3nmeoDpiyLmFNKimtj1y8dvPeg+dOfbVzVr8i4rPk41Ok97wnTZdMTpKvX5Sm+kRp0pRwTfJ1yz8oWpN8EvWeCaHasnuHrrn5bhjtbtjr1Zq36FLNnHtKM+cc0eCMXeod3KzuwbVqn7ZUbb3z+HmB+oeXvtw9uOSn7T2LftDYNPpIVfWMJaXl0wcKS3prYmPy/Q2k3gA4f0ha/nOk5r/0GF/4uz+5UZkQFBQxyR15/dCK9T95/svffOncnR//Xff0HRqcvkK9/YvVv2CJTl5/l/YceEAj8276ZXnt3h8lpM54Oju9b2FeZndfRdlIZW56b9YfAdt3ejPxN/io/2M9hRdc/7H+Pb3v5t17BP7UCf6PuXNfXxv9Q9cNlF4v9VrN05F7L7DTC4DK5WRfH1+/+KTMvrbOwae7pg8ot7RAwaHRCgrPVEPveo0suFo5eTOVkdWk+KRaRSeWKy61XLGJ9YpO7lNZ+zIdPnGVjp68Wet2ndT9j3xQ9z34Qd1x91O66dYndN31j+iyc/dq/6GbtXL1CU2fsVENXfNU0TJTte1z1NK9SG09CzRtcNmr02es+U1jy+j3S8v6H8zJ7xpJSGtqTkhvLIlOqfa4Y/J8eL1OLfj8+7vwPt/KMXkrjue3snF5s9r0/zi2F4eEdoXnpf7i6Y8+o0ef/SRguk6NnYOqbW1TVUubehf26Nw9+/Tg0zfqvg8+rg9+7ou68sYnNX1kzyv9Q+t/3de/7j/aWlZ+taVhwaWtjQvn1lbN7K6sGE6LT6yZ/DrAff37ebPX/e79drwLX7kXXN+F/2jel/yuPwJ/DEj/oEP3dSfRCwBy8fjxE8eHhnqmxkYnTUmKzpuSHJUTkhCVlOMKjyuKTktNKMzOjqzOyUtrKM4tqy7IKstOSCnLTk4uy8pMLUtNSy/PTM8qz0/PqSjLyK6sycuqqivMq64tLCysKatYmF9Y/q3s0lKlZuYrKz1bJUVFyqkp1Nqj63X5zee0ZPlSbV6xXovmrdbQ7CWaM3eF5szZrIG5O7Xl8Dlt3nta0xZs4G96VNTQo9LWTlV39qqytV9VrQOqautXbdew6lm1bTNUVD1d2WWDyq+cocLKERXVDKmsZVg1HXNUXjussqqZKi6f8fOcooEfZBQN/L+s4v7PZBT1P55TPnwir2z6oYzCnpNJOe070zJbmzMyGouS0mpL4xIrSyPjykrDoovLwqLyiuKSSxKi4/KjXJ7USJc7JTDUnRwUFp4YGh2Z4BMZHjPZE+J5o8P5T4H0/6pNv8lmZZKPJ2Kgpb//J0dP3wSYztHUgGgFh0QrMMSjIHe4QiIiFRQZobDMaBV2Jmv9qZm677lHtHHvFZqxYLPmLNmhJasOa+HifZo1su1XQwMbfgzgfqWheekH6hoWLS4pnlGUnNiU+BaB9l3/BXo3vAEvuL4b/pW8r/HdfAT+HMPLGxnQ70/cgQGBU6IiIkPiouOD42ITQxMSE1KTE9OmJcZlnUlKTHmsMKfioZrCgYeLM9qfz0jJ/4+M9Iwf5OZm/1tVYe7nK0ty/19DdcUPmyrKf5iXkf7DtKysHxaV1v6wtKr5h/VtHT+sqqv8YU1V8Q+ba8teaKore6Gxvur7jQ3VP6upqlR+AcCakavcjAIV5peqtKRM1VVlqq2uUEdzpwbaVqi5bqfKqjeqtnGeatpXq2Xeveqe/zRs9wRsdo5S0ztht1VKSC9VTGqlwuNrkJftslThiaWKTK5QfEa90vI6lF00oPySmcorHlF+6YhyK2cru3yOCotmq7hsVCXVoyqunqP8itkqrBp1Vn7pLBUWz3gtt7BfWfn9r2Tn9PwkM6vtBykZzT9MTG38IWz6h1HxVazSH8SnVHw1NrH0X6Jjiz8XF1/6wfTEgg8VpOV9Iis9//1Z6XkP5aZm35STmrs7NzVnUVF67lB+akZdbkp6am52fnRWSnpYVkKyf0x41KTzTPn17PR/yOnG/llm0JrK8omKi1y0fN3mXx04eK1yYPuTJrnkHxDGCpd/oEd+AaHI6y5N8QnRZL9A+Yf5KK00TVXtzeqeMaxVW3Zo+ea9WrnpsDZtu0xr153UkmWHNX/Jfs2Zv/vXgwObftjUsOirZYVDK0oKp0XGxxaYrG+fpz/GZt/N36u/+9fuBde/+38i7wt8Fx2Btwqkb2RD/0uuncB/48dPmBgQEBoQEuLuio+Nvz4jNfXxzNSMh9OSs55OSU75dkpy2kvxccmKiY5XRES45s1bqAcfelZdg9OUmRSnxU0FOjavW0MtNepoqVdbc52yc9KVnJGq/KpqFTU2qLajWYXlOcrBhJRXlKv84jwVlhSqsLSEVaSS4mIVA6iFrNKiSsC1UsXFlSoqrldF+ZDKq04h5z6vsvrnFBm/Q+l1i3Xn01/AyPSanvnw9zVzwWll5vQoLbtRKbl1iktrUGxSgxJSGgFerqfVsxoB13alFQ8orwwgLVsIWC+BrS5Vae0KGOxKlVcvV3n9YpU0LlFJ/RKVNixSeeNyFTcsU0HVApWWz1UBgJtTMqz03H4lZHUoIa1FMTxXdHy9IuIA9BjAPKZIYVEFCosuUHhsnlISec8ZhUpOzlVWZrbqCwtUXVDwakle7u9aCgt+21Ne8suqgqLv5mQXfqE4O+9D7aUl93RVll3bUVJyuq+8ZM9oY8PcroraxpSYlFh3kDvYb6q//4RxE30NUFl26ccKSEyPP7Jg+Tp1TFvCv1WOgoNhrqGRCsQEZouSrIKCw7mO9B4YpYCAKPkEAr6h4YpKitfAnD7tO3pE67cd1qrNp7Rh+zVav+VKrVx7QkvXHtLytUe1ZPFBzRre9nL/tDVfrK+ZfUt+VufyhNiqqDdhs2/8nL6LvmLvnpfqBdd3z7+V95X+/R2BvwRM/weQBgUHTQqL8PjFxEWFx8fHZSUlJeanpCQvys3N2p6bnbs9Pi7pzpiYuP9OTkxSQkKcuK74+CQlJiQqIT5WSQkJSuQ2V2Sg2kfqdfzcITV11SshKkrNeckaRMatzMlVZip/k8j9eZzE+HjFxEYqHBnSE+YBnCN57BjYZYKS0jKUmQ3Y2t/kFCojt0BZhUXKLSoBfAtVwGVBYY3yy1qQbwc0vOpyPf/Fl/Txz0tb9n1BFf17tPeakziF36/Dl1+p1s4ligdIo1KqFJFQ7jDWqIQaxRm4JhvANisus0PJuYPKKJ+n/JrlKqlbq8qWLarr3KH6jh2qbtuOjLyZtV7lbeuQitchI69XW+dmtXRsVWP7FjW0rFU5QFtcvUD5RTOVnDdNMVldik1t57lbYMhNCoutAFSL5YoqVnBUkUKi8pFjc+RihYRnKSIqQ2nJ2UpNzuAYpysjKUcFaTkAcKYiI1OUGJem4owcVWXlqTovXy1sPnqryl7rLKl6oTSz6CN5aXn35KUVX5GTUHwwMTZvXVh46rTgwMi8SZP8kgvKK+9bvPyAEpK7FBCSpBB3jIJCwhQCoIYgDweHxiATRygwOEYhobFOfTsgKA5WGysff4xiniA2E1UapeVp75FjOnvVI1q3825t3HarVm++TCs2nNSyVceRjk9o2Qrk44V7Ndi3QbVVox8qKxqcl5XaGuQF2b/tCcQLrn/b4+19tnf3EfhLzS0XDDeOjJienhCemZVQk56RsiojM3VvUmr81UlJsc9RB/16QW7WvxfkZL2Yn5Wm/OwU5eekKTMrVXHxcQqjLhceEaWoaFvRiuQyJg5Q5DIuLlqh0UiLQT4woyglxCVyGQOAxnCfOEXFxik6Jl7RsYlcZ0XFAxgJiopMYnFffo6I5j5xgHVKKkalbFa+UgGSzGwD2jxl5BUrP69ExYVlKiprVUpZu5Ye3MM55FX94te/0o0Pf1h1/dsVX9amxNxKhSVUKQl2mprRoPi0GphknRLT65SUWa/EzGbYa5Pi0tuUBBDmAIi55ctU2ozRp3+bemcc1Iw5pzQ87zINzr9UPbNOqqV/r1qnbcFdvEM9A7up8x7WyOgZar2Xaeb8o5o+tFODPRs0vXsV9dn5iikY4nX081zTFJeBNJ0Kk02sVURsFUBbDostgcUWy81yhRcqNKxAIWEAbjjM0p2jIFemQlxpCrblTgcQ0/g5lZWu0PBUecKTFRWRpPiITP4N8pQUn680VkpcIf8exS9Hxxb9ODoy58uBobEfLGlueOH01fdoeHifwsOL5XHnyuVOVCgAOnVqjCZPjdKUqZEKCIwDYOMA3gQFAbJBMNzAkBjanCLkE+BRZEq01u4a0n/+6Ft68kPf1t7jz2jTzru0buuV2nHgem3bzeW2y7V+w6VasfKYli6lRju86aXG6gX35mf1dYW708wJ/kaHtZfJvgPnJS+4vgMH1fuQ/1BH4E8B6pumGBmI2po81dc/IMhVExEZN5qYmLoxLS31cHp60pNpaYk/jo+PeTU6KgLADFM0KyM5QdlItmnJxkxjYKaRMM1YWBSgFxULw0xQrAOQ0YBgrCIByXDAMDo+UUlJBsBJAGm84hOTFZ+cqqSUJKWlZ3KZqUQYaVIqIJDMSsqEQWUBbtnOSkzhOrKorcQUZGNWWmYOIJinuMQcfs4BZHOoe9aqvKwOiRcAyalRRkmX2mcv1XV3PaRth65Rbe9C1TRjRCrvU1pWo1KRfBPTq3mOCiWkVik5q56/a1RafpPS89uQp9tgrW1Kpc5aUbVQbS1rNDi8U/NXXqVFax/VkvXPE1Dxcc3f+qTmbr5N05ec1tDcw1qw+KiWrb1ci9bdpyVrP66la76gWUufB2Bv1pzZBzR79m41tG1QVtkiZRbPUEb+dKUX9CqzAHnakYsbWdUw6grFUQuOZUXDqmMTKhQVXy5PbIkjH8cAktHxBTihi1iFiokvAjT5OSYfgM6HBeex4clTRCQSc0Q+q1Burrsi8+n75bbIQn7H9ehshXBMR9as0aqtB6lBNykZh3VScrnC4nNU2jJDNa2zVcDri4gsdf42KDgLRhvvsNqAEAPZeAUHxeqS4FBFFgbrrvcf17d/9COdvuHz2nvyC9p04FmdPfd+nT1+s04du0GnTt6uvQDt+g3HtHbDYa1bc0izhzb9tKF83mXZqR1JfDYvtDT9oZrsP9SX+P/izXjB9f/iqHuf8+/9CLxVQH1Tp6iff0gyddJelydsXZAr7L4Qd/h/uMMiX3GHRcN+ImA+YXK5IuV2RyHLRnFCjXGYaDwyb2JSomISYJVIwFHIt9Ew0Nj4ZG5Ppi4IYLISU9IcsExgxbPi0lO5TAM802GJgCM/x6WnKyU9Q6kAanJalpIzc3H95vE7wBLnb3IGt2dye0a2UvhdCoalZCTPxCxuzxhjrCkw1urSapWUAIypOTDoUmEu5rUVKjGjQkWlbSpt6ld565CqmodUUduvoopOFcBqcwqbef5qAKkMgCpDAi53GGt8JiwW9poI+KbkdCoxu0+JhTMJmVimBQv3aP3Gc9qx+4M6cfkLuu6OF3Xt7a9q27GfaM66j2lk5S1asP4azD1Xae22u7X/6Bf18IO/1rNPSqfOvqLpy76q1qFb1TN0XM1dO6nZrka+nq2skiFcyP3KLulVOqap5CxeW2aTkjJqOQbVMNtKjh+GqxQAF3NVAis5vUIZ2TXKzK1RVm61svMqlQsbz8+rVo7zczVsnt/x99nZ1dy3go1MDRuKBo53pVKSSwHQUqR4LgHuaAA7ICpTLvqEY2C38ckck6QKRXDMe5Yu0uKtG9lQbFF507C6p81TC5fp6bWoC7koEFnyRLJog3J5MuXrikE1iNGhK8/oqed/pOc+87LO3fFz7drzMZ3cc6suO3WLrrvmHl195jbt3XGF1m08oQ2bj2r3ztPatPqketpWfLykaLiTL+GbRVC+/rP/9/49/bt+fV5w/bv+5/G+uL/xEfhLYgEn+E7x9ffzC83xCwzuDQh2nQ31RH7BFRb5Y5fH82qIOwxJkZqas6KQHSOp8UUpHCYaFRsPW0qAHcJIkwFVmGYcrDM2MQUjDpcw2BgD2+QU53p8Mrdxe3xSGkwwHeYFiMJYY1KSFZ2S4tyelJyuRGqG0TCleNhpEkw1IS0dl64BMawVJpuQkQWjhLXycwIAnMRtKdyWCrAm5VBjzC1RCpIwdV9tWbVInb3dmIHSFRWTiayaC/AUAyylys6vUU5xgwpK61VY0UQ9tlGZ3JaeXwtbrFMq4JOYArgmFrNKkGUBr3SrszbymluUlA3YFQIiFQtURj112pxDsNObtef45/St//eifv2rV/VL1r985VUdvfTnWrrhM1q+7V6t3HqbNux6vx7/wLf08u9e5Rz2in7ys1d051OvauH6r2lw5g1Ix3sAqjXKq1ykrKIRZZZMV0ZRr9Jy2wBWFqw5EQYZn17FRqSc18NKKgNgy5UO2GbklFNvNgCtHQPX3Ar6esuUW1CpLIA2M78SE1i1Cni/+QW1yi2u4/03qLiAVVzD9UqOj606jmOD8rJg/BlVALCBM8eH+2bkNvH41RzvKqXk1fIam5WKUSy/ogGjWAOu4hqlwKqTAftEQDwpvQGFgnp1fIlC+VysP7hRL736Mu9f+saP2GBc+z1ddfkzuuX6h3TFZffoqtO368zB63T4wE3asOUKrd1yQvv2n9b2rSc0PLTtherKeWuSEyrMdPVGFuuVid+GE48XXN+Gg+h9iHf1EfhjLPV/hdafl3udtosAvwCXxx3WHeHy3O3xeL7r9kT8FGBVkAe3pwejSlj4WJ0UOTcKV28kYGqAGhXLz07t026HpVIPDUfuDYtOlIe6ZxgrAgdwFLdFssK5Hh7JfVhhDijbsvvEAnrUSmG34ecfJ9r+jueLsOdBLo5LSHMAONaRimG8gHKSAaqxVFpsUmCzqTBVY6/JuGVN8s3ILeQ+OQB9GhImrDghhetIxum5yMXUXjMLkVcLAKEiFqYnLjNzy1lVMDiAiZWWXab0bAAqh7prGswNcI2BxSXBxlJyOmCuvQB5twpqpqu2e4XaBnZpxuIT2nLsGT39iR9QxX3JAU3pt8767g+ky2/8L63a+SGt2X2vzl73jL7/45849d6x+7ysV16THnryZ8jK71fvzOOq692qssa1yNRzcREPKA3ZNTWnnffewuakEeA3U1UNr83kYNqEeI3JGeVKy4GFAq4pGWW8f94HbD2D95ORU8JlKbVobuP3WbDX3ALAFYNXXhEgCpBmcwyyHWCuhCUDyoBoPqBZSn26vLJLpVWdKqlpV2l9B3XhHpWUd+PQbuexWjhmTagFvC7k9CQ2IknI1snJlfz7leIYLmWDhYydANNOBIyLK1Q5o0unb71ezzz/CR24/G6NbrhOK7ZcrtXbj2nNtmPasee09u6/VAeO3KAd+27Quu2XkZp1VvsOXK6du05r/ujOFxur5l2dk9niPs9i/xjIvqu/5P8XL94Lrv8XR937nH8PR+DPYakXUowMVC8J9ZsUEBQQPER4wxOusPD/NjbqdiUoNBjTS3AqbRXRTgtFoJvb+V2YgWxktDwR8Qp1xyrEA4tFFh5bUQoMtTaMKKTieEwuMdyH6/a3ALXLE0MNLk6eKKRjADUuFtdwUhIn3hRYaRr10DE5OBKgDsPAFBGOickueb7oGKvb4gBGSk5BGk6njpoGQ03KpKaalQVYZMDK0pE482hfoR0lIw82m039MQ0QT+H1JvNaEpCrAVlYbgoSdAr122SYcUIizJjb4+NTx64nZcGqcwHwQthfAdI28mdCNrdj7kmCuSYVKTalBJdwGSysUcn57UrN61Rx5UzVta9Q08AmDa08rNufeF4/+81v9BrA+tqrv9OrrxrAvqLf/E564In/0sHTH9e+yx/R2Tue0zd+8FN+B6ICsPb/P/rxy7rl7i9q0YYbNW30gJqmbSSwAfdx1TCGqV6l5nbw3sfYagyAn4CDOSGxjM1IEW1E1FNTy/h9BeALsKZXsiko45iUcKxKWWXOSs8sdZhrNqzVWSYTs7LYRGSYPAwDzQVQC0tbkMjbeH/tKmEVV3aqtKZbxYBrcVUH1+2yRwWAa25JO329AGxBCxsSQDarhedHtsYAloB0nJBYybEEZKkJ2+uNT+B1pdYoBhacAvvNKx9EdehBtqedCVaekIOJjMfKr+hGtieso2tELcMLNLhgjUZX79TKDfu0fedR7dqFs3jR/tc621bcVlLYGnl+4+iVit+ms5MXXN+mA+l9mHfNEfhToPrGOqrDUieMu3hyjMedlhodtqkyxf1oa2H6TxOpiyIFyxcwDXDXKSRmVCGRgxhQ8ulTpI0iOEE+wbE4PQFap68xARCGfVJnHZOFcZvaikMGjgM0HcBC0gXYIqOSATdANQzGyqU5eePpd0xJw7yUmshlMkCZgsyYQl0VSZgWm2hacqK5XwysdWyZ+zceEw4MNi6T5ynk+fJZ6cjRY6anZOTiJCTimERaUaIz2ATggo1I5dIANgnQToNB8xph1faawiKTee22DHyTqAfyWrm/JzwF1y23R6fxu3S5I9KpE2Zy/2weIw92mA9LBMCoRcbAyKKobyYDdNkFXcohlam8a6U65u/S8r1X66ZHPq0f/eo3jtxp//0MYH3q+Z/o4NnntWHnrdqw7zptPn6X7n7mC/reL1/Ud3/1ij725Z/p3A2f08rNt6pv3h41dK+hR3YhADOi7GKMTLnI0Fn016bVAvIwwQQANbYQxzXmJIxJMfycmFYEW4W9InunppFMRehFcnoRteoSQK8CBgsbzYSxwkoNYDOQitO4LYu6bEFJIwy5lVYgmGk1oAaQGoCWVHc4wFoMay3m9uLqHkC1V0Wswqou5HTAtayL1UHoRpsDsrlF7TDeDuUUEKrB687OxZltbDvZGG0Nr4mF0zolrZXX3OS4rhNpa4qOq+XY17DJop+X5cEB7Y7IxdmMoSoqR+EpvBc=
</base64Binary>

NSData *d = [self decodeBase64WithString:@"...binary string here..."];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:d];
imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [imgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
    [imgView setImage:img];
```

But there is no image, I don;t know what I do wrong here :(

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk

Comment: Thanks I use code from 'Mike Ho' from that question. Decode method. But still no luck, I updated question...

Comment: Sorry it works, I returned a wrong byte array from web service. Thanks

Comment: Hi 1110,Can u please share me the code to convert Base64 with String?