# iPhone/iPad Base64 Image Encoded - Convert to UIImage

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimage, base64

I have a base64 encoded image recieved via a web service.

How do I convert that string to a UIImage?

Obj-c or C# answers are fine.

Ian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iPhone Monotouch C# this is how it is done:

```
byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String (Base64String);
string decoded = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString (encodedDataAsBytes);
NSData data = NSData.FromString (decoded, NSStringEncoding.ASCIIStringEncoding);
return UIImage.LoadFromData (data);
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to convert the base64-encoded data into an NSData. [This previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk) seems to be a good resource on how to do that.

Then you just pass that NSData object to `[UIImage imageWithData:...]`.

Answer (score 2):

I havent't tried but [here](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/20/encrypting-decrypting-base64-encode-decode-in-iphone-objective-c/) there seems to be a working sample code ;)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to get BahaiResearch's MonoTouch code to work -- an exception was thrown in NSData -- but was successful with the following:

```
byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = Convert.FromBase64String ( base64String );
NSData data = NSData.FromArray ( encodedDataAsBytes );                            
return UIImage.LoadFromData ( data );
```