# How to use base64 classes?

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, base64, decoding

I want get the image from an xml file which is encoded using base64.

I want to decode that data into image, but i don't know how to do that.

So please give me some instructions to find that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a nice code sample at the bottom of this post. Very self-contained...

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour

for more read [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk) post

Comment: There's a very nasty bug in the NSData category posted there, with the line: `realloc(bytes, length);`. This is wrong; you need to take into  account the return value of realloc.