# How to convert the base64 coded data into image in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, base64

I have base64 code in xml file, i get it into nsdata object, i want to convert data into image, I am trying to use cocoa base64 deocode classes but i con`t understand full about that classes, how can i send my nsdata into that classes? how can we use the base64 methods and classes?
please give me answer clearly, Please Dont give me the url, only give me how to work with that classes,
Thank you,
Anand

Answer (score 0):

Use base64 class to convert data,

Check below SO post for using base64

[How to use base64 classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429680/how-to-use-base64-classes/5429708#5429708)