# Transmit compressed file as xml to an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xcode4

- How do I pass a zip file in xml format to an iPhone?
- How do I retrieve to the compressed file using objective C and xcode?

Comment: can u b more clear...which data want to pass the content is not necessary that is secondary..

Comment: when i am parsing my xml i have to parse test.zip file also, so how can i parse this file??

Comment: cant get you just explain me step by step you  want..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Encode the zip's binary data (e.g. via [Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk)) and add to the XML data
- Transmit the XML to the iOS device (e.g. via [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use))
- Parse the XML to retreive the encoded zip data (e.g. via [`NSXMLParser`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSXMLParser), or [`libxml2`](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html) etc.)
- Decode the encoded zip data (again, with the same encoding method, e.g. Base64)
- Use Apple's pre-built zip library to [decompress](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/wiki/PageName) the decoded data

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do.. Pass an zipped xml file or want to pass zipped data to an xml file?

[Here is the library](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) for packing/unpacking the zip files