# How to convert a base64 encoded document into a multipage UIImageView in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, base64

The examples I have seen are geared towards C#.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to be more precise with your question. A document can be anything, e.g. an image, a word document, a pdf, etc. So where's your actual problem? Don't you know how to decode base64 to binary, or do you need to see how to create multipage images, or what?

Comment: Sorry about the confusing question. The document I am referring to is a fax (A PDF or a TIF) that could be multi page. I get on how to decode it. Just not sure how to have a mechanism to where a user could go through all the pages if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:
                  [NSData dataFromBase64EncodedString: stringBase64]];
```

Hope it helps. I don't know what you mean by "multipage UIImageView". The NSData category providing the dataFromBase64EncodedString method is [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. The base64 is a fax document spanning several pages.

Comment: Just a FYI to others, dataFromBase64EncodedString needs to be a implemented since it is not a base method of NSData