# Bad request -400 status code

Tags: iphone, xmlhttprequest

I am using http post method and passing base64econded string into xml. But it gives me 400 in response. XMl tag structure is valid. When I removed this base64encoded string from xml it works perfectly. But including it gives error(400). Would base64encoded string may contains any character that make my request invalid ? Any help is welcome.

Comment: What errors are you getting on the web server logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be caused by your boundary definitions not being 100% correct, eg. using wrong

```
Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=XXboundaryXX
```

instead of the correct

```
Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=XXboundaryXX
```

It may also be your boundary delimiters in the body that are not using correct syntax, eg. using wrong

```
--XXboundaryXX\r\n
```

instead of the correct

```
\r\n--XXboundaryXX\r\n
```

The following snippet should be correct for posting xml data, even for som nitty gritty older apache servers:

```
[request setValue:USER_AGENT forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[request setTimeoutInterval: 15];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

NSMutableData *postBody =  [NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"xmlstring\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[xml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:postBody];
```

I have previously [discovered error 400](https://github.com/TheRealKerni/QuincyKit/pull/17) if these delimiters were not 100% correct.

Answer (score 1):

Check your base64encoder. You can do it [here](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp)
I'm using solution from [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk/800976#800976).

If it's all right with your encoder, I suppose you're incorrect paste it into your xml (maybe with slashes or other 'bad' symbols)

Comment: Thanks for great link of checking base64 conversion +1.