# NSString is NULL

Tags: iphone

hiiii freinds please any guys say me why str is NULL i will be creasy

```
NSString *strData = @"issam  bey"   ;

NSMutableData *objNSData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:[strData dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]];


objNSData = [objNSData EncryptAES:@"12345678901234561234567890123456"];
//NSString* decryptedStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:objNSData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSString *str=[[NSString alloc] initWithData: objNSData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Comment: if i try with this code  its not null 
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc] initWithData: objNSData encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing encryption and decryption then read [Encrypting / Decrypting / Base64 Encode / Decode in iPhone Objective-C](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/20/encrypting-decrypting-base64-encode-decode-in-iphone-objective-c/).

For AES256 encryption-decryption, read [Adding methods to NSData and NSString using categories to provide AES256 encryption on iOS](https://gist.github.com/838614).

Answer (score 1):

NSString's `initWithData:encoding:` will try to use the specified data to create a string using the encoding you tell it to use. If it can't do that then it will return `nil`.

The fact that you tried a different encoding and got a value instead of `nil` should tell you what's wrong - your encoded data can't be represented by a UTF-8 string but can be represented by a Latin-1 string.

Just out of interest, why do you want to encrypt the data and then view it as a string again?

Comment: because i want save the encrypt string in my xml file and after i want decrypte and converted in MSUtableData

Comment: then you should take a look at base64 encoding it - that will make sure that it can be represented as a string - look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk

Comment: (base64 isn't encrypting - you will still need to encrypt it with AES and then base64 encode it :)