# How to decode a data using base64 and save as file object in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, base64

I am new to iphone development.. I am developing an iphone application in which i am getting file in form binary data encoded using base 64.. I m getting the data from web service.. Now i need to convert the binary data to file object and save it to my iphone simulator and need to open it... 
I ve searched and found the useful following links about base64 decoder:

[How do I do base64 encoding on iphone-sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk)

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour

But i dont know how to save decoded data as file??? Can anyone please tell me how to do that???

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[data writeToFile:@"Filename.txt" atomically:YES];
```

This way you can write raw data to a file. 
You can also check the [NSData documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) at apple.

Comment: I tried.. it runs well.. But where can i find the saved file??? Sorry I m new to iphone development :(

Comment: I finally found it :) Thanks a lot... But it is too slow :( Is that bcoz of base 64????

Comment: It can be, we cant say anything without profiling. Print the time taken and check whats the reason.

Answer (score 0):

To see your saved files on Files application under your project name folder, enable the below permissions on your Info.plist

[image]