# How to Decrypt in Objective C

Tags: php, objective-c, base64

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any base64 library on iphone-sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk)

I've the following php script that encrypted a string, now i need to decrypt the encrypted string in Obj-c

```
function encrypt($message, $initialVector, $secretKey) {
return base64_encode(
    mcrypt_encrypt(
        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
        md5($secretKey),
        $message,
        MCRYPT_MODE_CFB,
        $initialVector
    )
 );
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: look http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/20/encrypting-decrypting-base64-encode-decode-in-iphone-objective-c/

Comment: already asked... try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk

Comment: You could have issues with approval approving encryption - please use it wisely.  Your best bet would be to simply use SSL/HTTPS if you want end-to-end security over the network.