# Generate PDF with images from HTML in Swift without displaying print interface

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I generate a PDF in my `Swift` application from some HTML. I use a `UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter` and have code similar to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nyg/b8cd742250826cb1471f). I get the PDF as `NSData` and attach it to an email. The app does not show the PDF to the user before attaching it.

I'd now like to include some images. Adding their `NSURL` in HTML with my current PDF generating strategy doesn't work. How can I get `NSData` of a PDF corresponding to my HTML with images added? Here are some things I've tried:

1. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7072089/137744) suggests embedding the base64 image in the HTML and using [`UIPrintInteractionController`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiprintinteractioncontroller). This does give me a print preview with correctly-embedded images but how do I go from there to `NSData` corresponding to the PDF output?
2. I've seen some similar suggestions going through `UIWebView` but those lead to the same issue -- I don't want to show a preview to the user.

Comment: I have a couple of questions. Are the images local or are they url references in the html document? You want to add the images to your pdf document your creating? Can you post/mockup your current pdf output versus your desired?

Comment: @fragilecat The images are files on the phone. I have tried adding them with <img src= and the image NSURL but that doesn't work. Neither does embedding a base64 image according to the instructions I linked to. Visually there is nothing added to the PDF where the images should be.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The [`UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uimarkuptextprintformatter) does not seem to support the html `img` tag. Apple's documentation is not very informative here, it simply states that the initialization parameter is *"The HTML markup text for the print formatter"*. There is no indication of exactly what tags are supported by the print formatter.

After many tests the only conclusion I can draw is that [`UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uimarkuptextprintformatter) does **NOT** support displaying images.

So where does that leave people who want the convenience of creating PDF's from HTML content?

So the only way I have found to make this work is to use a hidden web view that you load your html content in and then use the web view's [`UIViewPrintFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html). This works but really feels like a hack.

It does work and it will embed images in your PDF document, however if it was me I would lean towards using [CoreText](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [Quartz 2D](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html) as you would have much more control of the pdf generation process, having said that I understand it might be overkill, I don't know the size or complexity of your html content.

So on to a working example...

**Setup**

It was useful to define a base url so that I could just pass in the filenames of the images I wanted to use. The base url mapped to a directory in the app bundle where the images are located. You can define your own location too.

```
Bundle.main.resourceURL + "www/"
```

[image: Copy Files Build Phase]

Then I created a protocol to handle document related functionality. Default implementations are provide by an extension as you can see in the code below.

```
protocol DocumentOperations {

    // Takes your image tags and the base url and generates a html string
    func generateHTMLString(imageTags: [String], baseURL: String) -> String

    // Uses UIViewPrintFormatter to generate pdf and returns pdf location
    func createPDF(html: String, formmatter: UIViewPrintFormatter, filename: String) -> String

    // Wraps your image filename in a HTML img tag
    func imageTags(filenames: [String]) -> [String]
}


extension DocumentOperations  {

    func imageTags(filenames: [String]) -> [String] {

        let tags = filenames.map { "<img src=\"\($0)\">" }

        return tags
    }


    func generateHTMLString(imageTags: [String], baseURL: String) -> String {

        // Example: just using the first element in the array
        var string = "<!DOCTYPE html><head><base href=\"\(baseURL)\"></head>\n<html>\n<body>\n"
        string = string + "\t<h2>PDF Document With Image</h2>\n"
        string = string + "\t\(imageTags[0])\n"
        string = string + "</body>\n</html>\n"

        return string
    }


    func createPDF(html: String, formmatter: UIViewPrintFormatter, filename: String) -> String {
        // From: https://gist.github.com/nyg/b8cd742250826cb1471f

        print("createPDF: \(html)")

        // 2. Assign print formatter to UIPrintPageRenderer
        let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
        render.addPrintFormatter(formmatter, startingAtPageAt: 0)

        // 3. Assign paperRect and printableRect
        let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8) // A4, 72 dpi
        let printable = page.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)

        render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")
        render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")

        // 4. Create PDF context and draw
        let pdfData = NSMutableData()
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect.zero, nil)

        for i in 1...render.numberOfPages {

            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
            let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
            render.drawPage(at: i - 1, in: bounds)
        }

        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

        // 5. Save PDF file
        let path = "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())\(filename).pdf"
        pdfData.write(toFile: path, atomically: true)
        print("open \(path)")

        return path
    }

}
```

Then I had this protocol adopted by a view controller. The key to making this work is here, your view controller needs to adopt the `UIWebViewDelegate` and in the 
`func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)` you can see the pdf is created.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, DocumentOperations {    
    @IBOutlet private var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        webView.delegate = self
        webView.alpha = 0

        if let html = prepareHTML() {
            print("html document:\(html)")
            webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)

        }
    }

    fileprivate func prepareHTML() -> String? {

        // Create Your Image tags here
        let tags = imageTags(filenames: ["PJH_144.png"])
        var html: String?

        // html
        if let url = Bundle.main.resourceURL {

            // Images are stored in the app bundle under the 'www' directory
            html = generateHTMLString(imageTags: tags, baseURL: url.absoluteString + "www/")
        }

        return html
    }
}


extension ViewController: UIWebViewDelegate {

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        if let content = prepareHTML() {
            let path = createPDF(html: content, formmatter: webView.viewPrintFormatter(), filename: "MyPDFDocument")
            print("PDF location: \(path)")
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Was wishing for a way that used HTML without being a hack but I think you've found the best strategy!

Comment: the sample project from this tutorial uses the img tag `http://www.appcoda.com/pdf-generation-ios/`, use the same code in my project and it doesn't work.

Comment: Your code almost works perfectly but for me generates the first PDF without images and the second one correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: Problem solved. Switched from UIWebView to WKWebView (checked Bart van Kuik answer) and everything works now thanks both for your help

Comment: I am working on the HTML to PDF using `UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter` and it is working fine when internet connectivity available but not work when no internet connection. Is there any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I fond an issue it was a font load from the URL so not working without internet, I made it local and it is working fine. ;)

Comment: The answer that UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter does not support images is incorrect. As long as you wait for it to complete before calling `UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage` it works just fine without any web views. Unfortunately you have to set an arbitrary wait time, but it does in fact work.

Answer (score 13):

Using parts from fragilecat his answer, I've put together a sample project with three viewcontrollers in Swift 5:

- The first one renders local HTML with one image using WKWebView, then
  exports to PDF
- The second one renders the PDF with another WKWebView
- The third one shows the print dialog

https://github.com/bvankuik/TestMakeAndPrintPDF

Comment: I was struggling with a similar problem getting css to apply. Your example finally helped me solve it. Thanks so much!

Comment: The image doesn't show when I run the sample-project app.

Comment: @fivewood I can't reliably reproduce the problem but I've added a small delay to allow the image to be loaded.

Comment: Please show how you added the delay to allow the image to be loaded.

Comment: @fivewood See updated project at Github: https://github.com/bvankuik/TestMakeAndPrintPDF/blob/master/TestMakeAndPrintPDF/ViewController.swift#L63

Answer (score 10):

Replace

```
let printFormatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: htmlContent)
printPageRenderer.addPrintFormatter(printFormatter, startingAtPageAt: 0)
```

with

```
let printFormatter = wkWebView.viewPrintFormatter()
printPageRenderer.addPrintFormatter(printFormatter, startingAtPageAt: 0)
```

where `wkWebView` is your instance of `WKWebView` in which you have previously loaded the HTML content `htmlContent` that contains an image, and `printPageRenderer` is your instance of `UIPrintPageRenderer`.

Comment: after wasting countless hours of time this was the only solution to work for me.

Comment: This is the best answer. It's not just that UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter has a problem with images, it has a problem with ALL links (including links to external CSS). So unless you can predict that your HTML will only have certain types of links, this is the most robust approach.

Answer (score 7):

My many hours wasted on this issue tells me `UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter` **does** support images. Two reasons for this:

1. As you say, the PDF shown by `UIPrintInteractionController` with a `UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter` shows the images correctly.
2. The following [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/pdf-generation-ios/) (also mentioned in the comments) actually manages to create a PDF with images using `UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter`. I've investigated and found the reason for this was that the HTML code was loaded beforehand in a `UIWebView`. It looks like `UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter` relies on some `WebKit` component to render its images.

I'm aware I'm not providing any solution but to me this is clearly an iOS bug. I don't have iOS 11 so maybe it has been solved in this upcoming version.

I've described the bug in detail [here](https://github.com/nyg/HTMLWithImagesToPDF) along with a sample app that allows creation of PDFs using the different print formatters available.

NB: I've only managed to get Base64 and "external" (i.e. http://example.com/my-image.png) images working.

Comment: Very interesting analysis! Thanks so much for sharing. Will be interesting to see what we find in iOS 11, I haven't tried it either. @pete-hornsby's solution solved my short-term problem but it does feel like there should be a more direct way to do it.

Comment: @HélèneMartin Thanks! Well, I installed iOS 11 and the bug is still here! I've filed a bug report with Apple... http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6067400759836672

Comment: Too bad it isn't addressed yet, thanks for filing the bug report!

Comment: looks like I faced this issue too, I managed to make it work in my test project but when I move code to my production application it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

First, create UIWebView instance

```
var webView:UIWebView?
```

After that create the function for init webView and add UIWebViewDelegate in the controller,

```
func initWebView(htmlString:String) {
  self.webView = UIWebView.init(frame:self.view.frame)
  self.webView?.delegate = self
  self.webView?.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
}
```

After that write PDF conversion code webViewDidFinishLoad method

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){
    if(webView.isLoading){
        return
    }
    let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
    render.addPrintFormatter((self.webView?.viewPrintFormatter())!, startingAtPageAt: 0)

    //Give your needed size

    let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 384, height: 192)

    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect:page),forKey:"paperRect")
    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect:page), forKey: "printableRect")

    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData,page, nil)

    for i in 1...render.numberOfPages-1{

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
        render.drawPage(at: i - 1, in: bounds)
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    //For locally view page

     let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
     let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("file.pdf");
     if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath:fileURL.path) {
         do {
           try pdfData.write(to: fileURL)
           print("file saved")

         } catch {
             print("error saving file:", error);
       }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like many people here i wasted hours solving this. I used base-64 images, not external images. The following works well for me with images loaded in the `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,..." />` html tag and also with css using `background-image: "url('data:image/jpeg;base64,...)"`.

Here is what i ended up with:

- The original question asked for not having to display the webview before generating the PDF. I did not need that but if you do just make it invisible as [@Pete Hornsby (accepted answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40472190/3936644) suggested.
- [As @fivewood mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51219315/3936644) do not use `UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter` but `webPreview.viewPrintFormatter()` instead, i have no idea why but it works like that.
- **Required**: wait for the webview to be loaded before generating the PDF ([pointed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40320983/3936644)).

```swift
let renderer = UIPrintPageRenderer()

// A4 in portrait mode
let pageFrame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8)
renderer.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: pageFrame), forKey: "paperRect")

// webview here is a WKWebView instance in which we previously loaded the page
renderer.addPrintFormatter(webview.viewPrintFormatter(), startingAtPageAt: 0)

let pdfData = NSMutableData()

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect.zero, nil)
for i in 0..<renderer.numberOfPages {
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
    renderer.drawPage(at: i, in: UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds())
}

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

// DONE: pdfData contains the pdf data with images.
// The following tutorial (mentioned several times in this thread) shows
// how to store it in a local file or send it by mail:
// https://www.appcoda.com/pdf-generation-ios/
```