# Base64 Encode and decode

Tags: objective-c

i need to encode some string(like UID,PWD) using Base64 in objective C  how can i do it. 
can anybody share the code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 0):

I am using the [xmppframework](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/) library for my iphone project, and there are these two NSData Categories that take care of encoding(decoding) to(from) base64.

[NSDataAdditions.h](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/source/browse/Categories/NSData+XMPP.h)

[NSDataAdditions.m](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/source/browse/Categories/NSData+XMPP.m)

You should be able to use this category in your project.

Answer (score 0):

While Sailesh's answer is probably the easiest way, Apple also provides some (more low level) example code in the "Security Transforms Programming Guide".

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecTransformPG/SecurityTransformsBasics/SecurityTransformsBasics.html

However this is only available in Mac OS 10.7 or higher.