# Base64 encoding in Objective-C with Rest API

Tags: objective-c, restful-authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any base64 library on iphone-sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk)

I need to send an authorization request using REST API in Objective C with the support of Base64 encoding. It seems like objective C doesn't have any inbuilt method for that. Can anyone suggest me a good Base64 encoding library for this?

Comment: Just google base64 objective-c. You'll find a dozen blog entries explaining how to do it and providing reference implementations. Matt Gallagher's is quite often sourced and used.

Comment: Searching SO for base64 [ios] gave pages and pages of results. Please search before you post. It's common cortousy.

Comment: yes there were many. But most of them had lots of issues. I just wanted to confirm a good library that anyone of you have used before

Comment: I suggest using Matt Gallagher's then. His has some very minor issues but I think even those are updated since I last checked. Implementing Base64 in c is very simple and whatever you choose you only need to proof and fix a couple dozen lines of code. So just pick one, check/fix it and continue with your core dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NSData+Base64.h](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine/blob/master/NSData+Base64.m)
 and [NSData+Base64.m](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine/blob/master/NSData+Base64.m) resolved my issue. Below I have included the code snippet to show how you can use this classes to encode your strings.

```
NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", [Configs userName], [Configs password]];
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *enCodedAuthValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodingWithLineLength:80]];

NSLog(@"Encoded Value %@",enCodedAuthValue);
```

Configs is a class where credentials have been configured