# How can I transfer and instance of a class through SOAP?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an app that communicates with a web service VIA SOAP.  So far the communications have been strictly string values and the like.  Some of these values in classes, some not.

My question is: Is it possible to pass an instance of a class through SOAP?

Something with the syntax like..

```
//class declaration in .h
 Myclass class
```

in the .m

```
 class.string = @"stuff";
 class.integer = 5;
```

then create the SOAP string

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<stuff xmlns="http://website.com/">
  <class>%@</class>
</stuff>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>,class];
```

Is something like this possible as long as the web service knows how to handle it?

Comment: Are you looking to transfer an _instance_ of a class, or are you looking to define a new class entirely?

Comment: transfer an instance of the class.  Complete with all the stored values and everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transfer an instance of a class, look into the [NSCoding](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol.

The [Archiving and Serializations Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i) has some examples on how to do what you're asking, specifically the [Encoding and Decoding Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000948-BCIHBJDE) chapter.

Comment: I have no control over what is done on the webservice side.  Its written in VB I believe.  Will it be able to handle this information if I pass it?  Or will they have to go through a process to decode the object?

Comment: VB doesn't understand Objective-C binaries (ehm, obviously). Serializing the object is only good if you intend to store it and then get it back to the objective-c side. It is a bad idea if you intend to pass values to the server. In this case just write some XML from Objective-C.

Comment: There was no requirement that VB was involved in the question. I assumed the instance was being stored by the web service. I would go with JSON or XML in that case. Simply encode the object's state in one of those formats and decode it in VB.

Comment: Ok, yeah my mistake.  This object is being passed to the server and will not be used again by my app.  I was going to mention that just now but you guys found out already.  I'll use the XML option in that case.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSKeyedArchiver.

```
// serialize object to data with the given key
+ (NSData*) archive:(id<NSCoding>)object key:(NSString*const)key {
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver encodeObject:object forKey:key];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    [archiver release];
    return [data autorelease];
}

+ (id<NSCoding>) unarchiveKey:(NSString*const)key data:(NSData*)codedData{
    // unarchive
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:codedData];
    id<NSCoding,NSObject> object = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:key];
    [unarchiver finishDecoding];
    [unarchiver release];
    return object;
}
```

and you need to edit the object to serialize to implement NSCoding for its ivars:

```
#pragma mark - NSCoding

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder {
    [super encodeWithCoder:coder];
    [coder encodeObject:self.myVar forKey:@"someArbitraryKey"];
    // ... other ivars
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if(self) {
        self.myVar = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"someArbitraryKey"];
        // ...other ivars
    }
    return self;
}
```

So create two methods for archive and unarchive, and implement NSCoding in the object to serialize. Then take the NSData and [make it Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk) to add it to SOAP. Basically that. I didn'tn compile anything, good luck. Read Ben's link.