# JavaScript Base64 encrypted url, decrypt in Objective-C

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, base64

i'm trying to decrypt an url generated in javascript, this is what i find in the html page:

```
Base64.encrypt(Base64.decode('Zk05NUQ6YUZVcERKd3pCdlkucUIrbnFtdldTdW5mbkZnZFk5TVFpV3N0NHRaTF9FV1RWSHhjX1pFMDNacmxwUy5JalF3Yw=='));
```

my question is how i can decrypt it in Objective-C, i have add a Base64 in my Xcode project, and i have decode it using the function:

```
+ (NSData*) decode:(NSString*) string;
```

and decode it, but how i can encrypt it? what is the:

```
Base64.encrypt
```

how i can handle it in Objective-C?

**EDIT 2:**

i have tried to use the decode base 64 and the output is this:

```
fM95D:aFUpDJwzBvY.qB+nqmvWSunfnFgdY9MQiWst4tZL_EWTVHxc_ZE03ZrlpS.IjQwc
```

what i have to do then? the javascript do this Base.encrypt, what i have to do?

Comment: Base64 is **not** an encryption. It's an encoding.

Comment: this html page use that script to generate url, how i can generate it in objective-c?

Comment: related post on base64 in obj-c: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812442/generating-a-unique-id-in-objective-c/8812485#8812485

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some utility class or some category to do the decoding & conversion.

And you can find something suitable within the answers [on this very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk).

Comment: i know how do the decode, but how i can do the encypt like that script do?

Comment: If you look in the linked question, you'll see a method named "`base64DataFromString`".

Comment: ok, that function return NSData, and then what i have to do with that Data?

Comment: and now I'm thoroughly confused as to what you are actually doing.  Are you trying to *encode* or *decode* a string? What's the big picture purpose here?

Comment: decode...but i can't understand what does Base64.encrypt...i want do the same thing in objective-c

Comment: The purpose of Base64-encoding (not encrypting) is to take a binary data stream and represent in a text format that can be included in text transmissions (e.g. JSON or XML). The Base64-decoding (not decrypting) simply takes the Base64-encoded text stream (that was presumably included in a JSON or XML transmission) and retrieves the original binary data (e.g. an image or something like that). In short, the purpose of Base64 is not to encrypt (i.e. keep the content from prying eyes), but rather to facilitate transmission via a text-based format. Base64.encrypt seems like a misnomer to me.