# Get transaction id from paypal sdk 2.0.1

Tags: iphone, ios7, paypal, paypal-sandbox

How to get Transaction id from paypal sdk 2.0.1, i searched a lot but i am stuck at getting transaction id from paypal sdk 2.0.1.

check response below;-

```
{
client =
 {
    environment = sandbox;
    "paypal_sdk_version" = "2.0.1";
    platform = iOS;
    "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
 };
response =     
  {
    "create_time" = "2014-04-01T07:02:34Z";
    id = "PAY-3J588144TJ947892HKM5GJCQ";
    intent = sale;
    state = approved;
  };
"response_type" = payment;
 }
```

Above code i got pay id but not getting transaction id, how can i get transaction id.???

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the PayPal SDK documentation to [Verify Mobile Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/). Have a closer look to [Sale](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#sale-object) and [Transaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#transaction-object) object.

`Sale` Object has `id` field:

```
id |    string  ID of the sale transaction.
```

All you need is to interact with `REST API`.

**EDIT:**

Try to send curl request using `NSURLConnection` and `NSMutableRequest` as described in examples:

1. [Converting a CURL command for Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982707/converting-a-curl-command-for-objective-c)
2. [Objective-c equivalent of curl request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451205/objective-c-equivalent-of-curl-request)
3. [Basic HTTP Authentication Using iOS](http://cybersam.com/ios-dev/http-basic-access-authentication-with-objective-c-and-ios)

Comment: Hello . thanks for responding. i try this api but i am getting fail request, https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5YK922393D847794YKER7MU i use this api but not working can u seggest me right way.?? how to get it.

Comment: How do you call it ? Have you passed an access token and set content type in the request ?

Comment: hi.. no i just pass the https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-3J588144TJ947892HKM5GJCQ'. so how can i pass access token and content t. how to get token and content type.?

Comment: How to get accessToken .?

Comment: Follow this link, you need to setup app and get the necessary data from there. There are link at the left side. Please explore them as well.

Comment: Hi...i want to know that how to get access token and where is the link.?

Comment: Hi.. i got access token and  i pass content type and access token like this  [request setPostValue:@"application/json" forKey:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer {%@}",accessToken]  forKey:@"Authorization"]; but request got fail.

Comment: try to remove `{` and `}`

Comment: Ok, pass `content-type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `grant_type=client_credentials`

Comment: ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/%@",strID]]];
    [request setPostValue:@"application/json" forKey:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",accessToken]  forKey:@"Authorization"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(RequestFailed:)];
    [request startAsynchronous];