# Get paypal transaction ID - iOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, http, curl, paypal

Hi i am using paypal SDK in my iOS application. After successful transaction it gives the below response

```
{
client =
 {
    environment = sandbox;
    "paypal_sdk_version" = "2.0.1";
    platform = iOS;
    "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
 };
response =     
  {
    "create_time" = "2014-04-01T07:02:34Z";
    id = "PAY-3J588144TJ947892HKM5GJCQ";
    intent = sale;
    state = approved;
  };
"response_type" = payment;
 }
```

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779083/get-transaction-id-from-paypal-sdk-2-0-1) and [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/) tutorials, but I am not getting a clear picture.
I am using  NSURLCOnnection HTTP methods to do server connections.
How can I do the cur request in HTTP method.

Answer (score 0):

Dave from PayPal here.

First, if you're indeed using version 2.0.1 of the PayPal iOS SDK, you should update. The [current release](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/releases) is either 2.3.2 (for Xcode 5) or 2.4.0 (for Xcode 6).

Once you have obtained the proof of payment shown above, your app should sent that record to your own server. It will then be your *server* that performs the steps explained [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/).

Comment: Show payment details  --> /v1/payments/payment/payment_id
I tried with this REST Api but it does not return full response all the time. I need a transaction fee but it only returns some times. And I see it returns different response in different state of transaction like Pending/ Completed etc.