# How to convert this cURL command to objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, curl

I'm trying to convert this cURL command to objective-c but can't find any information on "-i" and "-u" with regards to objective-c libraries.

```
curl -i -u "username" "https:domain.com/v1/authenticate"
```

Comment: What have you tried? How are you trying to replace curl in objective-c code? Are you using a library? Do you know what -i and -u do? What have you attempted to replace their invocations? Your question lacks all of this information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a CURL command for Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982707/converting-a-curl-command-for-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

Google ["man curl"](https://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=curl&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%20unstable%20sid&format=html&locale=en), gee that was easier than creating a SO question.

> -i
>                 (HTTP) Include the HTTP-header in the  output.  The  HTTP-header
>                 includes  things  like  server-name, date of the document, HTTP-
>                 version and more...
>
> -u 
>                 Specify the user name and password to use for server authentica-
>                 tion.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! No need to be an asshole about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -X GET 
--header "Accept: application/json" 
--header "app_id: 999999" 
--header "app_key: xxxxxxx" 
--header "Dev-Mode: true" "https://api.infermedica.com/v2/symptoms"
```

Objective-C code

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    //CURL

    //curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "app_id: 795edb00" --header "app_key: c68cb95e54ec04f44544bb5fd7ab5125" --header "ev-Mode: true" "https://api.infermedica.com/v2/symptoms"


    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.infermedica.com/v2/symptoms;app_id=795edb00;app_key=c68cb95e54ec04f44544bb5fd7ab5125"];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:str];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc ]initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    arr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    NSLog(@"%@",arr);
```