# iOS: Convert data into string and emailing it

Tags: ios, database, url, core-data, import

I've encountered an interesting solution to importing/exporting data through email. This particular solution doesn't involve attaching any files and also "encrypts" the information, such that it's not easy to decipher.

I'd like to know if anyone has an idea about how this is done.

Basically, this app allows you to export a custom-selected set of data by emailing you a link. The link is a URL scheme that opens the app and asks if you want to import the data. The data looks like it's encrypted, but I'm not sure. Below is an example of a link that the app generates. Does anyone know how this is accomplished?

Thank you!:

appofinterest://#;;bmFtZQ==;TmV3IFByb2ZpbGU=;;cHJvZmlsZVBob3Rv;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;;c3R5bGU=;MA==;;dXNlc1NJVW5pdHM=;MA==;;QXBwb2ludG1lbnQ=;;ZGF0ZU9m;MjAxMi0wMS0xNSAxMDowMA==;;TGFiUmVzdWx0;;cmVzdWx0;NTY=;;dGVzdFR5cGU=;VGVtcGVyYXR1cmU=;;ZGF0ZU9mVGVzdA==;MjAxMS0xMi0xMyAwMDowMA==;;TGFiUmVzdWx0;;cmVzdWx0;NzQ=;;dGVzdFR5cGU=;VGVtcGVyYXR1cmU=;;ZGF0ZU9mVGVzdA==;MjAxMS0xMi0yOSAwMDowMA==;;TGFiUmVzdWx0;;cmVzdWx0;MzUgwrBD;;dGVzdFR5cGU=;VGVtcGVyYXR1cmU=;;ZGF0ZU9mVGVzdA==;MjAxMS0xMS0xMCAwMDowMA==;;TGFiUmVzdWx0;;cmVzdWx0;ODU=;;dGVzdFR5cGU=;VGVtcGVyYXR1cmU=;;ZGF0ZU9mVGVzdA==;MjAxMi0wMS0wMyAwMDowMA==;;TGFiUmVzdWx0;;cmVzdWx0;NjQ=;;dGVzdFR5cGU=;VGVtcGVyYXR1cmU=;;ZGF0ZU9mVGVzdA==;MjAxMS0xMS0xMCAwMDowMA==;;TGFiUmVzdWx0;;cmVzdWx0;NDYgbmcvbWw=;;dGVzdFR5cGU=;UHJvc3RhdGUgU3BlY2lmaWMgQW50aWdlbiAoUFNBKQ==;;ZGF0ZU9mVGVzdA==;MjAxMS0xMC0xMCAwMDowMA==;;TGFiUmVzdWx0;;cmVzdWx0;NjM=;;dGVzdFR5cGU=;VGVtcGVyYXR1cmU=;;ZGF0ZU9mVGVzdA==;MjAxMi0wMS0wNiAwMDowMA==;;TGFiUmVzdWx0;;cmVzdWx0;NTg=;;dGVzdFR5cGU=;VGVtcGVyYXR1cmU=;;ZGF0ZU9mVGVzdA==;MjAxMS0xMi0xMyAwMDowMA==;;TGFiUmVzdWx0;;cmVzdWx0;OTQ=;;dGVzdFR5cGU=;VGVtcGVyYXR1cmU=;;ZGF0ZU9mVGVzdA==;MjAxMS0xMi0yMiAwMDowMA==;;TGFiUmVzdWx0;;cmVzdWx0;NTk=;;dGVzdFR5cGU=;VGVtcGVyYXR1cmU=;;ZGF0ZU9mVGVzdA==;MjAxMS0xMC0xMCAwMDowMA==;;TGFiUmVzdWx0;;cmVzdWx0;OTkuOCDCsEY=;;dGVzdFR5cGU=;VGVtcGVyYXR1cmU=;;ZGF0ZU9mVGVzdA==;MjAxMS0xMi0xMCAwMDowMA==;;TGFiUmVzdWx0;;cmVzdWx0;NjU=;;dGVzdFR5cGU=;VGVtcGVyYXR1cmU=;;ZGF0ZU9mVGVzdA==;MjAxMS0wNy0xMCAwMDowMA==;;TGFiUmVzdWx0;;cmVzdWx0;OTc=;;dGVzdFR5cGU=;VGVtcGVyYXR1cmU=;;ZGF0ZU9mVGVzdA==;MjAxMS0wNy0xNSAwMDowMA==;;TGFiUmVzdWx0;;cmVzdWx0;MzIgwrBD;;dGVzdFR5cGU=;VGVtcGVyYXR1cmU=;;ZGF0ZU9mVGVzdA==;MjAxMi0wMS0wNSAwMDowMA==;;TWVkaWNhdGlvbg==;;ZnJlcXVlbmN5;b25jZSBwZXIgZGF5IChxLmQuKQ==;;cm91dGU=;SW50cmF2ZW5vdXMgKEkuVi4p;;ZHJ1Z05hbWU=;TXR4;;aXNDaGVtb0RydWc=;WWVz;;dG90YWxMaWZldGltZURvc2U=;ODUgbWc=;;c3RhcnREYXRl;MjAxMi0wMS0xNSAwMDowMA==;;c3RvcERhdGU=;MjAxMi0wNS0xMCAwMDowMA==

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just [convert your data to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk) (which is the case here*). Remember that URI are not (practically) unlimited in length and might, like the link you posted, be a little meaningless for your users.

(*) in the case you posted, the data is separated by semi-columns, for example "TmV3IFByb2ZpbGU=" is base64 for New Profile, and the big chunk in the middle is a base64 encoded PNG. Absolutely not secure - since it's not encrypted in any way, but could be fairly easily

[image]

Comment: Hey Remy, thanks for your help! This is what I'm looking for. I'll try to figure out how to implement it.