# need NSData to ascii85(adobe) NSString converter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, ascii, nsdata

I need to convert `NSData` to `NSString` with ascii85 encoding.
I've found this answer: [Any ascii85/base85 encoder/decoder for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580246/any-ascii85-base85-encoder-decoder-for-ios) but the category used there uses RFC1924 character set. But I need an adobe version. Please, help me with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using [this category](https://github.com/cbrauchli/Ascii85-Encoding-Categories)
but I removed _b85encode and _b85decode charsets and replaced
`outputBuffer[outputLength + (4-j)] = _b85encode[x % 85];` with `outputBuffer[outputLength + (4-j)] = (x%85)+33;`,  `x = x*85 + _b85decode[chars[i*5 + j]];` with `x = x*85 + chars[i*5 + j]-33;` and `x = x*85 + _b85decode[chars[numBlocks*5 + i]];` with `x = x*85 + chars[numBlocks*5 + i] - 33;`

Comment: Can confirm this one uses Ascii85 format instead of RFC1924.