# iOS asset path from Core Data used in HTML img tag

Tags: objective-c, ios, email, uitableview, core-data

I'm creating an app that lets users take and store photos in a Core Data graph, then email these photos in a table from within the app.

I've been able to save the photos within the SQlite database by converting the asset paths to NSURL values and referencing them  - to stop the database from suffering from memory issues.

My last task is to allow users to email their photos in a nicely laid out table, complete with a description of the photo. This is automatically generated from the UITableView that the images are displayed in.

I'm using the following to generate the HTML email:

```
- (NSString *)generateHTMLBody {

    NSString *res = @"<HTML><body><table border=""1"">\n";

    for (int i=0; i < [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count]; i++) {
        NSString *rowCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.", i+1]; 
        NSString *tmp = (NSString *)[imageList objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *imageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src=""%@"" />",tmp];

        res = res = [res stringByAppendingString:@"<tr><td>"];
        res = res = [res stringByAppendingString:rowCount];
        res = res = [res stringByAppendingString:@"</td>\n"];
        res = res = [res stringByAppendingString:@"<td>"];
        res = res = [res stringByAppendingString:imageString];
        res = res = [res stringByAppendingString:@"</td>\n"];
        res = res = [res stringByAppendingString:@"<td>"];
        res = res = [res stringByAppendingString:tmp];
        res = res = [res stringByAppendingString:@"</td></tr>\n"];
    }
    res = [res stringByAppendingString:@"</table></body></html>\n"];
    return res;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is load the images from the Core Data graph into an HTML img tag. I'm pulling the following asset path into the var tmp:

```
assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=2F62642E-00B3-4D85-82D2-A6A1F064F2CE&ext=JPG
```

However, this isn't working. How would I load these photos into the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you sending the email? Via a `MFMailComposeViewController`? I would have thought that you'd be attaching files via `addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:`. That's probably easiest.

Alternatively, if you want to build a custom, pretty html body with images included in there, you probably want to pursue a base64 encoding of your images. You then put something like  `<img src="data:image/gif;base64,XXX">` in your html, where `XXX` is the base64 encoding of your image. When I did this, I encoded using Google GTMBase64 in GTM:

http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/

There are also articles here about base64 libraries, e.g.

[How do I do base64 encoding on iphone-sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk)

Comment: Hi Robert, yeah I'm using MFMailComposeViewController to send the email, and did look into attaching the images to the email, however I want them to be nested in the table I'm creating.

Comment: Very good. Then I think that base64 encoding of the image is probably the way to go.