# Upload file while sending JSON from iOS to PHP script on web server

Tags: php, objective-c, ios

I'm currently sending JSON data from my iOS app to a PHP script on my web server.
Here's the code I'm using in iOS to send the data:

```
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:newDatasetInfo options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/upload.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

And on the PHP side:

```
$handle = fopen('php://input','r');
$jsonInput = fgets($handle);
// Decoding JSON into an Array
$decoded = json_decode($jsonInput,true);
```

How can I modify both the iOS code and the PHP code to be able to also upload a file from the iOS app to the PHP code, that the PHP code then uses to write to disk locally? The file would be an audio file.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711481/sending-file-from-ios-to-php-using-post

Comment: Yes, but that's not with sending JSON data.

Comment: You'll want to send a POST request using the `x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding, then use the `$_FILES` variable in the PHP code.

Comment: @H2CO3 You mean `multipart/form-data` I hope?

Comment: @Jack Oh, yes. Sorry, it was 1AM here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about Obj-C, but basically you need to use the `multipart/form-data` container, e.g.

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="xx"

--xx
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Content-Length: 12345
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="file"; filename="music.mp3"

<contents of mp3>

--xx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 123

<contents of json data>

--xx--
```

With PHP you can access the data using:

```
$_FILES['file'] // the uploaded file

$_POST['data'] // the json data
```