# Fast base64 image encoder , for iOS?

Tags: ios, image, encoding, base64

I need a fast base64 image encoder. I searched on stackOverflow and found this great question here with the same topic ([How do I do base64 encoding on iphone-sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk))

BUT some of the solutions provided are extremely slow... and the fast ones seem to "leak" from everywhere... so what i am asking is  to encode an image of about 1mb in less than a second to base64 if possible. Anyone know a good and solid class to do that? Thank you for reading my post.

*To prevent someone from saying "did u check on google" , yes i did but whether the solutions are extremely slow (40 seconds to encode) or have many many MANY errors...

**Please provide a solution that u know it works , and not just a link u just googled because i tried many and are really slow..

Comment: Can you name the fast one that leaks? Perhaps that can be addressed.