# encryption decryption between php and objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, encryption

i am going to start my application, which contains  encryption decryption for objective c .

in this app of mine , i have received datas from php webservices and i have to make decryption of those datas.

in the other case , i have to save my datas in my local database in the encrypted manner, and then i have to just send those datas from my database to php server. and they (php server) have to decrypt those data.

so for this communication which will be best, secure and approved my apple encryption/decryption algorithm ?

php side they are using AES_ENCRYPT.

is there any library for it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk

Comment: php side they are using AES_ENCRYPT.

Answer (score 0):

What I implemented is to transfer data between asp.net server and iOS application. I encrypted my some important data with AES.

The AES encrtyptor library I used for iOS app is [FBEncryptor](https://github.com/dev5tec/FBEncryptor). With the same `key` and `iv`, those encrypted data can be decrypted at asp.net server which is written by C#. Hope this helps.