# Simple string encryption/decryption algorithm

Tags: ios, encryption

I need to encrypt and decrypt NSStrings. It doesn't have to be secure (at all!) just unreadable to an average user. Something as simple as a shift cipher would work alright, but I would like an algorithm slightly less obvious to the user.

Is there something built in to the iOS sdk that does this already? Maybe RSA encryption? Or a simple to code algorithm that wouldn't look like a one to one character exchange?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

It's completely non-secure, and although unreadable it will be a fairly obvious encoding scheme for anyone remotely knowledgeable in IT.

Implementation details : [How do I do base64 encoding on iphone-sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

What about [ROT13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13)? It was already used in ancient Rome, fun to use, not save.

Or use [string encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) as used for URLs in web technologies.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a substitution cypher. Just prepare a 255 byte array with indexes from 1 to 255, scramble the array and replace each byte with the corresponding index value.
Another easy cypher employs a key of length N, consisting of positive and negative offsets. Each byte of the nsstring gets shifted - the first by the value of the first offset, the second by the second and the k-th by the value of the (k mod N)-the. It is much harder to spot for the average, unmotivated user, and almost as easy to implement as a single shift cypher.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the other suggestions, you could also try [Vigenère](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigenere_cypher), which seems to meet your design criteria: simple and unreadable.