# Encryption and signature creation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, encryption, md5

I need to undergo a process of creating a signature from the following process in Objective C:

1. ASCII encode an NSString
2. Hash the results with MD5
3. Perform bitwise operation on the resulting bytes (&127)
4. Convert to Base64 string

I am stuck on where to start. I am able to complete this task in C# but am at a loss in Objective C or even ANSI C.

I have got as far as getting the UTF8String from the initial NSString  using:

```
[NSString UTF8String]
```

Hopefully you can help.

Comment: Why are you using ASCII? It is not a lossless conversion. Tackle each of these steps individually, each one is easy to search for.

Comment: It is not my definition - it is a set of instructions supplied by a third party that I have to follow. I can handle points 2 and 4 but 1 and 3, in particular, are causing me issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read [String Conversions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html)
2. Dowload [NSString MD5 Category](https://github.com/H2CO3/NSString-MD5) by H2CO3
3. Take your pick of [Base64 encoders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk)

You mentioned you are having problems with String conversions, this is what you want to convert to ASCII:

```
NSString* src = @"";
NSData* data = [src dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion: YES];
NSString* ascii = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

To perform the bitwise operations is a little complicated. You will want to do this in straight C, like so:

```
NSString* src = <MD5 hashed result>
NSMutableString* dst = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity: src.length];
for(NSUInteger i=0;i<src.length;i++) {
    unichar c = [src characterAtIndex: i];
    [dst appendFormat: @"%d", (c & 127)];
}

//Base64 encode dst
```

The 3rd party should tell you how to do it if they require it.

Comment: You are very right - they should have examples if they want compliance. Thank you very much for taking the time to help. I will try it out now.