# How can I get the public key of a secure webpage using swift

Tags: swift, ssl, openssl

I need to get the public keys of a secured website programmatically with swift

In openssl i can get public key with this command:

```
openssl s_client -connect the.host.name:443 | openssl x509 -pubkey -noout
```

How can do this in swift code?

ps: I need .der file

Comment: does this answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808101/seckey-from-public-key-string-from-server-in-swift

Comment: @workingdog no, it's not I want to get public key programmatically without open ssl