# How to make a REST API request, with a certificate provided as String, in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, rest, certificate

I have to make a `POST` request to an endpoint, where that request should be included with the client certificate. The problem here is, I receive the client certificate cert-chain as a string(the format as below).

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

MIID9jCCAt6gAwIBAgIQNwHqBnL+445eqCUKVWroxDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCB

XufZCQ4mDV3MU0z+wsS4alR7b410V5Wet36pjUkrWtHEI2dBWZFzCOay19Vpb2V2

0M/zl07YpoZYxw==

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Note: The string is much bigger :)

I tried to convert the string to `NSData` object and create a `PKCS12` object. But converting to NSData itself fails.

How I converted is

`let dataDecoded  = Data(base64Encoded: certChainString, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)`

This returns empty data object as the size of `dataDecoded` is 0 bytes.

How can I send the POST request with the certificate when the certChainString is provided?

Comment: Use the proper library in your language to load certificates, it is not just Base64 data to decode.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek yeah that's the issue, I don't get the certificate to load it directly, I just get the String value

Comment: How are you making the request? Are you using `URLSession`?

Comment: @robmayoff yes,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to convert it while it still includes `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`?

It isn't valid base64 with those included, so remove them first.

```
let certChainString = """
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

...

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
"""
let certString = certChainString
                      .replacingOccurrences(of: "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", with: "")
                      .replacingOccurrences(of: "-----END CERTIFICATE-----", with: "")

let dataDecoded  = Data(base64Encoded: certString, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
```

If the API request returns important data, please consider reading more on [Security topic](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security) first or use [frameworks](https://github.com/svdo/swift-SecurityExtensions).

#### Edit:

```
import Foundation

let certChainString = """
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

... cert here ...

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
"""
let certString = certChainString
                      .replacingOccurrences(of: "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", with: "")
                      .replacingOccurrences(of: "-----END CERTIFICATE-----", with: "")

private var key: SecKey?

if let dataDecoded  = Data(base64Encoded: certString, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters),
   let certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, dataDecoded as CFData)
{
    var trust: SecTrust?
    let policy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509()
    let status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(certificate, policy, &trust)

    if status == errSecSuccess, let trust {
        key = SecTrustCopyKey(trust)
    }
}

print(key)
```

Comment: No, I have removed `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`. Actually, I have reformed the certChainString this way, `let modifiedCert = certChainString.replacingOccurrences(of: "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "-----END CERTIFICATE-----", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)`

Comment: @AzeemMuzammil Well I just tried in Playground, and dataDecoded is actually 106 bytes, not 0

Comment: With which String you tried in the playground? Cuz, I receive the certChainString by scanning a QR code (A Json Object), then I extract the certChainString and do the modification. after that If I convert to Data it gives nil.

Comment: @AzeemMuzammil Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808101/seckey-from-public-key-string-from-server-in-swift) too

Comment: I tried with a [valid certificate](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-NSX-Data-Center-for-vSphere/6.4/com.vmware.nsx.admin.doc/GUID-BBC4804F-AC54-4DD2-BF6B-ECD2F60083F6.html) string, and dataDecoded does contain the Data, so maybe take a look at the actual string you get and try with it.

Comment: now I can get the data, and get a SecCertficate object using `SecCertificateCreateWithData(_:_:)`. Now how can I use this certificate to authenticate my  request from `urlSession(_:didReceive:completionHandler:)`