# SecCertificateCreateWithData always returning null

Tags: ios, objective-c, security

I'm currently working from the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319849/get-seckeyref-from-base64-coded-string). Here is the code:

```
    SecCertificateRef   certs    = NULL;
    SecPolicyRef        policy  = NULL;

    NSString *publicKeyString = @"MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCeJ8N8fuGShAJnniDg4yuRrxrG61ZF2T24eXSEH87jCJmLbc+MV70AgP/LC8btzSU4FFP56lBmDcmW+Prupf5gO1RXhjPIlET73t5Ny1I3ze+xaShAA9qB0c9dNb26NxVd95wCHNmQhon9qBFmTVZb0CdgscxYcDuLOGskDnATrwIDAQAB";
    NSData *publicKeyStringData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:publicKeyString options:0];


    certs = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFDataRef) publicKeyStringData);
```

Based on the post if the `certs` variable is NULL then data was in an incorrect format. I checked the above public key and it is indeed base64, so I can't see why `certs` would be NULL?

Comment: Have you checked that the certificate data is valid?

Comment: Have you got the solution for same. I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 22):

Certificate can have these extensions: .CER, .CRT, .DER, .PEM. And it can be encoded in two ways: DER and PEM. This apple method accepts only DER encoding.

If you have .CER or .CRT extension you have to find out if it is encoded in DER or PEM encoding. (If there is .PEM or .DER extension it is clear.)

To check the current encoding, change the extension to DER and try to read it:

1. Rename the file (certificate.crt -> certificate.der)
2. In terminal: openssl x509 -in certificate.der -inform der -text -noout

If you see an error it is likely PEM encoded certificate and you need to change it to DER encoded:

1. Rename back to crt (certificate.der -> certificate.crt)
2. In terminal: openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -outform der -out certificate.der

// source: https://support.ssl.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19/0/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates-and-how-to-convert-them

Comment: Thanks mate, well explained and solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you are checking in iOS version 10 or greater, then `SecCertificateCreateWithData` will return `nil`.

something changed in the Security Framework in iOS10. Either "SecCertificateCreateWithData" is broken in iOS10 or the method has become more strict.

Looks like a bug.

You can see bug report at: https://openradar.appspot.com/28618141

Also read related gitHub post here: https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/16045

***Edit:***

From the thread here: [Why SecCertificateCreateWithData is always return nil?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/68789)

Also check the documentation for the same here: [SecCertificateCreateWithData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1396073-seccertificatecreatewithdata?preferredLanguage=occ)

> The most common reason for `SecCertificateCreateWithData` to return `nil`
>   is that the data isn’t a valid certificate.  A common problem is that
>   folks try to pass in a `PEM` format certificate, whereas
>   `SecCertificateCreateWithData` requires `DER`.  If you open the
>   certificate with a text editor, do you see Base64?  Or do you see
>   binary goo?  If you see `Base64`, you’ll need to convert the certificate
>   to binary (`DER`) form before passing to to
>   `SecCertificateCreateWithData`.  For a single certificate that you
>   include in your bundle, you can just pre-convert it using Keychain
>   Access on the Mac.

Comment: I've just run the code on an iOS 9 device and I'm still getting a NULL

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
  NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:publicKeyString options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];


certs = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorMalloc, (__bridge CFDataRef)data);
```

Comment: do you have a swift based solution for your answer @Ketan Parmar

Comment: let data = Data(base64Encoded: publicKeyString, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
if let data = data as? CFData? {
    var cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorMalloc, data)
} this is my swift implementation and data is always nil , any clue

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1396073-seccertificatecreatewithdata?language=objc):

> ### SecCertificateCreateWithData
>
> Creates a certificate object from a DER representation of a certificate.
>
> ...
>
> ### Return Value
>
> The newly created certificate object. Call the CFRelease function to release this object when you are finished with it. Returns NULL if the data passed in the data parameter is not a valid DER-encoded X.509 certificate.

So, perhaps the NSData you're trying to use isn't in a DER format?