# Send BASE64 Encrypted Image as String and other info in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

I am storing an image in form of String using Base64 encoding. I wish to send that image to API and get jSON object response. I have deployed the same in Android using ArrayList, but Since iOS does not have ArrayList. How can this be done.

```
ArrayList nameValuePairs = new ArrayList();

  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("serialnumber",ReplaceString(UserData.objUserData.getencryptedTerminalid()).trim()));
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobileimei",ReplaceString(EncryptionHelper.encryptText(telephonyManager.getDeviceId())).trim()));
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("submerchantguid",ReplaceString(EncryptionHelper.encryptText(Payment.merchantId)).trim()));
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("transactionid",ReplaceString(EncryptionHelper.encryptText(Payment.transactionId))));
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emailid",ReplaceString(EncryptionHelper.encryptText(userEmail)).trim()));
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobileno",ReplaceString(EncryptionHelper.encryptText(userMobile)).trim()));
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("signature",encodedSignImage));
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photo",encodedPhotoImage.trim()));


  InputStream is;
  // open data output stream
  OutputStream dos;

  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

  HttpPost httppost = new

  HttpPost(Constants.INFO_SUBMIT);

  httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

  HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

  is = entity.getContent();

  int ch;
  StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
  String responseString = "";

  while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) 
  {
   b.append((char) ch);
  }

  responseString = b.toString();
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
  statusString = (String) jsonObject.get("Status");

    }
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is objective-c?  Looks like either C++ or Mono to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are really three separate questions here, which I'll answer individually:

1. In terms of communicating with a web service, you should check out [RestKit](http://restkit.org) or [ASIHTTPRequest](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tree/) or [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or something like that. If you're interested in writing your own, you'd use `NSURLConnection` which you can see discussed in the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE). You can also look at the various examples you'll see in the [NSURLConnection Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html), such as [SimpleURLConnections](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009245)
2. In terms of parsing/creating JSON, you can use [`NSJSONSerialization`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
3. In terms of base64 coding, I've successfully used [Google GTMBase64 in GTM](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/). But I'd suggest you look at [How do I do base64 encoding on iphone-sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk)