# Print In app purchase transaction receipt?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, receipt

Iam using following code for In App purchase and and its working but i wanna know the transaction receipt .I know its in encoded format but i have to send that to my server.So please tell me where i can find this ? how to add code for that currently iam using this code

[Please click here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial)

```
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Transaction completed." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}
```

**is this  a receipt ??
"SKPaymentTransaction: 0x147e1860"**

Comment: http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/29/at-newsstand-and-subscriptions/   refer this tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NSString *receiptStr= [Base64Encoding base64EncodingForData:(transaction.transactionReceipt) WithLineLength:0];
```

Try this it may help you.

Comment: in complete transaction method

Comment: SKPaymentTransaction: 0x147e1860>" is this a receipt?

Comment: transaction.transactionReceipt this data is your receipt

Comment: it is a secure data so you have to convert it to base64 and then you can send it to your server for receipt varification :)

Comment: yes dear :) if you have any other concern regarding this please lt me know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/how-do-i-do-base64-encoding-on-iphone-sdk   in this link one answer with 84 votes are theer is that enouhg

Comment: Yes this is the class i am also using  :)

Comment: not working am not able to call that base64 encoding category

Comment: what is the issue u r getting now

Comment: i have add one category but not able to create object for that

Comment: have you included the category class in .m file

Comment: yes, then i tried to create one object..its a NSString catagory so i should use that for creating object? or the file name? for creating object

Comment: @Navi i didnt understant what is the issue in creating a category yaar have u ever made any category?

Comment: i have made before.but this time its not working let me check something

Comment: please check it there must be some issue in that else you can directly call that method.

Comment: what iam doing is  :  1.added the .h file im my .m file     2.trying to call the methdoe in .h category file ?how i call that methode using object?