# How to serialize UIImage to JSON?

Tags: ios, nsjsonserialization

I am using

`imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgvw.image);`

and while posting

```
[dic setObject:imagedata forKey:@"image"];
```

after

`NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dic options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&theError];`

now app is crashing Terminating app due to uncaught exception '`NSInvalidArgumentException`', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (NSConcreteMutableData)

Comment: Take a look here -> http://www.json.org/ It seems you need to learn more about JSON before you try to use it.  The key section on this page is the **Values** section.  Take a look at the kinds of values that are allowed in the JSON standard.

Comment: What is imagedate you are setting in dictionary ?

Comment: I am pretty sure you are using wrong dictionary. Where have you allocated dictionary and what is imagedate here ?

Comment: borrrden is completely right. The NSJSONSerialization documentation also lists at the very top what kind of objects can be serialized (and NSData is not among them).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to convert your UIImage to NSData and then convert that NSData to a NSString which will be base64 string representation of your data.

Once you get the NSString* from NSData*, you can add it to your dictionary at key @"image"

To convert NSData to a base64 type NSString* refer to the following link:
[How do I do base64 encoding on iphone-sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/how-do-i-do-base64-encoding-on-iphone-sdk/800976#800976)

In a more pseudo-way the process will look like this

```
UIImage *my_image; //your image handle
NSData *data_of_my_image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(my_image);
NSString *base64StringOf_my_image = [data_of_my_image convertToBase64String];

//now you can add it to your dictionary
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dict setObject:base64StringOf_my_image forKey:@"image"];

if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:dict]) //perform a check
{
        NSLog(@"valid object for JSON");
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];


        if (error!=nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error creating JSON Data = %@",error);
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"JSON Data created successfully.");
        }
}
else{
        NSLog(@"not a valid object for JSON");
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
NSData *imageData  = [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.photoImageView.image, compression)  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

```
const unsigned char *bytes = [imageData bytes]; 
NSUInteger length = [imageData length];
NSMutableArray *byteArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i length; i++)
{
    [byteArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedChar:bytes[i]]];
}

NSDictionary *dictJson = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              byteArray, @"photo",
              nil];
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictJson options:0 error:NULL];
```

Answer (score -3):

you can Convert Your image in ti NSData like:-

**if PNG image**

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
```

**if JPG image**

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.jpg"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

**and you can store it in to CoreData may be like this way is usefull for you:-**

```
[newManagedObject setValue:imageData forKey:@"image"];
```

**You can load like :-**

```
 NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self yourFetchCOntroller] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[selectedObject valueForKey:@"image"]];
// and set this image in to your image View  
    yourimageView.image=image;
```

Comment: The question title is misleading. The question was how to send an image via JSON. I don't see how saving the image in Core Data helps here.