# Swift 3 and IBM Cloudant upload an image

Tags: swift3, cloud, image-uploading

I tried a lot of things to upload a simple `UIImage` to IBM Cloundant with Swift without any success. I also tried Alamofire.

Please help me.

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToUpload)

Alamofire.upload(imageData!, to: url)
.authenticate(usingCredential: credential)
.responseJSON { response in
   debugPrint(response)
}
```

The error is bad type, it needs to be `JSON`. So I tried like that:

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToUpload)
let dict = ["image": imageData]
let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: .prettyPrinted)

Alamofire.upload(data!, to: url)
.authenticate(usingCredential: credential)
.responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

Comment: What did you try? What did not work?  Please share code what you have done so far.

Comment: I have delete a lot, but the problem is I think to put the image in JSON

Comment: To serialize a `UIImage` to JSON, please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306730/