# Need to translate some C# to Obj-C

Tags: c#, .net, objective-c

So I'm doing some authentication against a web service. The code example I've been given is in .NET C#, a language I have never used.

I need some assistance in understanding whats going on in the C# so I can replicate it in Objective C. txtUserPwd is a text box with the users password in it. txtRecivedIV is the IV which is pulled from another service (some encryption occurs later on).

```
// Pad entered password to multiple of 16
int padLen = 16 - (txtUserPwd.TextLength % 16);
int totalWidth = txtUserPwd.TextLength + padLen;
byte[] password = textConverter.GetBytes(txtUserPwd.Text.PadRight(totalWidth, (char) padLen));

// Decode entered IV
byte[] decodedIV = Convert.FromBase64String(txtReceivedIV.Text);
```

I'm guessing that the first part pads the string out with some whitespace but I'm not sure how much white space or where. I'm guessing that the second part converts the received IV from Base64 to text and then converts it into a byte string?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code translation service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int padLen = 16 - (txtUserPwd.TextLength % 16)`

Sets `padLen` to the difference between `txtUserPwd.TextLength` and the nearest multiple of 16 beyond the length of the password. If password is 8 characters, it would be. If the password is 12 characters, `padLen` would be 4. If the Password is 20 characters, it would be 12.

`int totalWidth = txtUserPwd.TextLength + padLen;`

Just summing some stuff.

`byte[] password = textConverter.GetBytes(txtUserPwd.Text.PadRight(totalWidth, (char) padLen));`

Let's break it down. `txtUserPwd.Text.PadRight(totalWidth, (char) padLen)` should just pad the value to a total length of `totalWidth`. This will make it a multiple of 16 characters in length. `textConverter.GetBytes` would convert the padded string to a byte array. Likely using the default encoding. All padding is added to the end of the string.

`byte[] decodedIV = Convert.FromBase64String(txtReceivedIV.Text);`

This just converts the base64 string into a byte array.

Comment: Hi, thanks thats very helpful. In the "PadRight(totalWidth, (char) padLen)" what character does it use to pad out the string? I'm guessing it adds the padding to the end (the right) of the string? Thanks again!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36f2hz3a.aspx says it uses the character represented by `padLen`. And it should add it to the right of the string.

Answer (score 0):

The first part makes sure the length is any multiple of 16. The rest is [base64 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/how-do-i-do-base64-encoding-on-iphone-sdk).