# Base64 Encoding in objective-c IOS-App

Tags: ios, objective-c, base64, ios7

I am using this function in Java to generated a secrect URL Parameter:

```
new String(Base64Encoding.encode(String.valueOf(vendorId), Bean.getSessionId()))
```

And i need to do the same in my ios app, can someone help? Only found examples for base64 encoding. But not how to say this is my "salt". (Sessionid).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do base64 encoding on iphone-sdk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/how-do-i-do-base64-encoding-on-iphone-sdk)

Comment: It's not really duplicate - he is asking about using Salt in base64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ready to use function for Base64 in iOS. However you can use one of existing implementations and libraries. You can check on of those:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64/

https://gist.github.com/0xced/1901480

Salt is just concatenated to the String. So if your Salt is "MySalt" than it's combining Salt with your string and do Base64 on concatenated String. You need to make salt value equal on both devices - just define it as your secret on both platforms.

Comment: This not about the Base64, but about the salt.

Comment: ok, just done the include. can you tell me how i set the salt?

Comment: check update I've done

Comment: Hm, but does the Java function only connect the Strings? So like string1+String2? But Shell the Salt does Not be Used for the entcryption?