# What is the equivalent of Android's Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP) in iOS?

Tags: ios, base64

On Android, I have part of the code that's doing Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP) where b is a bytes array. What is the equivalent of this in the iOS world?

Comment: Apple does not supply base64 encoding, you must find and use a 3rd party solution. It seems that Apple does not approve of base64 encoding--perhaps it is to googley? Year after year we Radar requests for it and Apple responds with a deathly silence.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do base64 encoding on iphone-sdk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/how-do-i-do-base64-encoding-on-iphone-sdk)

Comment: What's the solution? i need no wrap data

Answer (score 0):

See if Matt Gallagher's [base64 code](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html) will work for you. I have used it an trust it to be correct. See the section "Handling Base64 on the iPhone".

Answer (score 0):

**iOS**

```
func base64EncodedStringWithOptions(_ options:NSDataBase64EncodingOptions)-> String
```

**Available in iOS 7.0 and later.**

**Constants**
Encoding64CharacterLineLength
Set the maximum line length to 64 characters, after which a line ending is inserted.

Encoding76CharacterLineLength
Set the maximum line length to 76 characters, after which a line ending is inserted.

EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn
When a maximum line length is set, specify that the line ending to insert should include a carriage return.

EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed
When a maximum line length is set, specify that the line ending to insert should include a line feed.

**Android**

NO_WRAP

Added in API level 8
int NO_WRAP
Encoder flag bit to omit all line terminators (i.e., the output will be on one long line).

Looks like you want to use base64EncodedStringWithOptions and NOT include any of the options since all of the iOS options contain some kind of line terminator.