# Error in implementing adColony in iOS sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have an app already uploaded in the app store.I am **implementing AdColony** add for this.In my app ARC in disable then as per the instruction in the docs (Enable ARC only for AdColony by adding “-­fobjc-­arc” to your project’s Other Linker Flags setting under the Build Settings tab) I tried to enable ARC.But I am getting linker error "no such file or directory: '­-fobjc­-arc".

Also, in step 5 of Adcolony implementation guide it is written that we have to write "-ObjC" Or "-force_load PATH/TO/LIBRARY/libAdColony.a"  also to run the code in the Other Linker Flags.

People who have disabled ARC need to use both the above process.I tried all different way but still stuck.

**Console Output:**

"2013-09-21 15:02:45.689 ][1812:1d603] ADCOLONY 2.0.1 [info] AdColony library version: 2.0.1.33 production
2013-09-21 15:02:46.139 ][1812:21707] **+[NSData adc_dataWithWeaklyEncryptedBase64EncodedString:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x25db7e0"**.

Please suggest me some way out for this.

**Edit:**

Last Time I was using old API.But now I have downloaded the new framework that is updated in late August.The app is not crashing on using -fobjc-arc.But still it is not showing add.

**Console Output:**

2013-09-21 17:08:39.614 AfricanMoviesNewsiPad[2839:1d603] ADCOLONY 2.2.2 [info] AdColony library version: 2.2.2 production
2013-09-21 17:08:40.025 AfricanMoviesNewsiPad[2839:21807] +[NSData adc_dataWithWeaklyEncryptedBase64EncodedString:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x29fe7e0

I have also checked all the required frameworks are added.Not getting any clue.

Comment: Have you taken all required frameworks? check it once.

Comment: there might be some problem with base64 encoding check below url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/how-do-i-do-base64-encoding-on-iphone-sdk?rq=1

Comment: I have the same issue : dataWithWeaklyEncryptedBase64EncodedString

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've installed the latest version (ADCOLONY 2.2.2) on github.

I followed the instruction of installation. Because my project didn't use ARC, and I had the same error message as yours. Then it turned out, I had a typo in "-Objc" which should be "-ObjC".

Below is what I put in the other link flags,

-ObjC -fobjc-arc

It worked for me.

Someone also had the same problem, but no solution yet.

http://www.giderosmobile.com/forum/discussion/2468/adcolony-plugin-for-ios-video-ads-network