# how to convert NSData to image in ios

Tags: objective-c

I'm using web service to retrieve data. But I'm unable to convert data to image. I'm receiving data from server but when I'm converting to image it is showing null.

Comment: this must be covered somewhere on this site

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Show code what you have tried?

Answer (score 19):

Convert NSData to UIImage :

```
NSData *data = ... // data that you received
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Convert UIImage to NSData (png) :

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

Convert UIImage to NSData (jpg) :

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.jpg"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

Comment: i'm using saop service to retrieve data.during xml parsing they are stored in string to get the image i'm converting it to nsdata and from nsdata i want uiiimage here im getting the problem

Comment: yes so replace YOUR_DATA by your NSData

Answer (score 3):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:...];`. I'm curious what are you using now?

Answer (score 1):

In one of your comments, you suggest that the images "are stored in string". If this is the case, then image may have been base64-encoded (a common mechanism for representing binary data in a string). You should clarify this with the provider of this SOAP service.

If it has been converted to a base64 string, then you'll have to convert that back to the raw binary format before you can use `imageWithData` or the like. There are a variety of base64 alternatives listed in response to [How do I do base64 encoding on iphone-sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/how-do-i-do-base64-encoding-on-iphone-sdk)