# Send image to asp.net web service from IOS

Tags: ios, asp.net, web-services, soap

In my IOS app i need o send a image to ASP.NET Web Service . I am trying to the image in bytes form & then convert it back to image form on server side. 
Now i am using these line to convert image to bytes in IOS :

```
 NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation([Mybutton currentBackgroundImage]);
```

this line give a bytes of 734,775 word, which is too much, so it can not be send a soap request .
So , now how can i acieve this goal ??????

when call the service usiong soap request then it gives me this error :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body><soap:Fault>
<faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring>      System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
   There was an exception running the extensions specified in the config file. ---&gt; System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded.
           at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()
          at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_InputStream()
         at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
         at    System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type,             HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse              response, Boolean&amp; abortProcessing)
</faultstring>
<detail />
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am making an app for chating , so on registeration of user i have to upload the user image to web server and when it search for people around him/her, then also i want to return imae from the web service 
how can i do thse two things ?
First put image on web server & then retrieve from web server .
Thanks A lot

Comment: Hii have you found solution for your question? If so, please help me in this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29077775/upload-image-from-iphone-to-server-using-wcf-service-using-soap

Comment: @pasha pash - I was also facing the same problem and the below answer was what I did to solve the issue.Feel free to get back to me in case if you problem remains unsolved

Answer (score 3):

- You can reduce the memory footage of the image using JPEG image
  compression

  ```
  lowResolutionImage = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(highResImage, quality)];
  ```

  where quality is between 0.0 and 1.0
- Don't send the image as raw binary over the internet turn the binary into base64 string

> because some media are made for streaming text. You never know some
>   protocols may interpret your binary data as control characters , or
>   your binary data could be screwed up because the underlying protocol
>   might think that you've entered a special character combination.
>
> Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/how-do-i-do-base64-encoding-on-iphone-sdk/17571101#17571101) on how to convert into base64

- As you are using IIS for hosting your application, then the default upload file size if 4MB. To increase it, please use this below section in your web.config

  ```
  <configuration>
      <system.web>
          <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
      </system.web>
  </configuration>
  ```

  For IIS7 and above, you also need to add the lines below:

  ```
  <system.webServer>
     <security>
        <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  ```

Note: maxAllowedContentLength is measured in bytes while maxRequestLength is measured in kilobytes, which is why the values differ in this config example. (Both are equivalent to 1 GB.)

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29198483/730807) for another question that'd be helpful to you