# AFHTTPRequestOperationManager file upload returns 500 server error

Tags: ios, afnetworking

Im trying to upload camera taken photo to webservice with afnetworking.

this my upload part code :

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(500.0f, 500.0f);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
[_imagedata drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.9f);

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"user": "test_user"};
    [manager POST:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/webservice.aspx" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
        [formData appendPartWithFormData:imgData name:@"image"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Im using Asp.net as my webservice.

this is my server side code :

```
    string USER = Server.UrlDecode(Request["user"]),
    SqlParameter prmUser = sc.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    prmUser.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    prmUser.Value = USER;


    HttpFileCollection MyFileCollection = Request.Files;
    if (MyFileCollection != null && MyFileCollection.Count > 0 && MyFileCollection[0] != null)
    {
        SqlParameter prmImage = sc.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Image);
        prmImage.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        byte[] buf = new byte[MyFileCollection[0].ContentLength];
        MyFileCollection[0].InputStream.Read(buf, 0, MyFileCollection[0].ContentLength);
        prmPhoto.Value = buf;

    }
sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

now everytime i run program this error apears :

```
Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)" UserInfo=0x1555ff60 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x16a94010> { URL: http://www.mywebsite.com/webservice.aspx } { status code: 500, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 3420;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Wed, 01 Apr 2015 15:56:21 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.5";
    Via = "1.1 magellan-front (squid/3.5.1)";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Cache" = "MISS from magellan-front";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://www.mywebsite.com/webservice.aspx, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500),
```

the detailed error :

```
[HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (image=&quot;...�5�Ƨ&amp;�����&lt;I
�(�ep��K�,�=mp�...&quot;).]
```

also the webservice works well with android **HttpFileUpload** method.

Comment: Please set the responseSerializer before posting. You are setting it inside the Post.

Comment: This could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client

Comment: The following links could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/29198665/730807,http://stackoverflow.com/a/29198483/730807

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to find the basics of this, here is the [link](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1619#issuecomment-29130783)

What it seems from your code is that the client side seems to have a issue. Why don't you try using `appendPartWithFileURL:name:fileName:mimeType:error:`, and say if that doesn't work then the issue has to be from server side.

I don't know much about ASP.NET, but could you once verify your way how you are trying to read the file. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760510/foreach-on-request-files) where in I found something interesting you might wanna try implementing.

The enumerator on the `HttpFileCollection` returns the keys (names) of the files, not the `HttpPostedFileBase` objects. Once you get the key, use the `Item` (`[]`) property with the key (filename) to get the `HttpPostedFileBase` object.

```
foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];

    ...
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try uploading the image as a file (`appendPartWithFileData`) rather than as form data (`appendPartWithFormData`), and setting a content-type:

```
[formData appendPartWithFileData:imgData name:@"image"
    fileName:@"image.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
```

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15413152/1469259